# How can I implement dynamic programming for a function with more than one argument?

Tags: programming, recursion, memoization

> Dynamic programming is a technique for avoiding the repeated computation of the same values in a recursive program. Each value computed is immediately stored. If the value is needed again, it is not computed but simply looked up in the table. [(1)](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=N1QZPTL250YC&pg=PA156)

I use [orthogonal polynomials](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18) a fair bit in my work. Since *Mathematica* supports only [the classical ones](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OrthogonalPolynomials.html), I often have to write my own functions. For instance, the monic Charlier polynomials satisfy the three-term recurrence

$$C_{n+1}^{(a)}(x)=(x-a-n)C_n^{(a)}(x)-an C_{n-1}^{(a)}(x)$$

with $C_0^{(a)}(x)=1$ and $C_1^{(a)}(x)=x-a$.

If I want to be able to use monic Charlier polynomials in *Mathematica*, I can do this:

```
CharlierC[0, a_, x_] := 1;
CharlierC[1, a_, x_] := x - a;
CharlierC[n_Integer, a_, x_] := (x - a - n + 1) CharlierC[n - 1, a, x] -
                                 a (n - 1) CharlierC[n - 2, a, x]
```

The problem with this route, of course, is that the effort expended to generate, say, `CharlierC[20, a, x]` can't be used for evaluating `CharlierC[50, a, x]`. For a one-argument recursive function (e.g. Fibonacci), dynamic programming is fine and dandy for saving evaluation effort. For a multiple-argument function, imagine what would happen if one had used the definition `CharlierC[n_Integer, a_, x_] := CharlierC[n, a, x] = (* stuff *)` and then executed `Plot[{CharlierC[5, 1, x], CharlierC[6, x, 2]}, {x, -1, 1}]`.

Is there a way to reap the benefits of dynamic programming on a multiple-argument function, while storing only results where the recursion variable (`n` in the Charlier example) changes?

Comment: As I am sure you know `CharlierC[n, x, a] == (-1)^n HypergeometricU[-n, 1 - n + x, a]`, so there is no need to use the recursive definition for this one.

Comment: @Sasha: I certainly do, but I also deal with even more complicated polynomials than Charlier polynomials; I just wanted a simple example of an *unsupported* polynomial system.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this related to probability anyhow? Like I just learned that Charlier polynomials are orthogonal with respect to Poisson measure, which makes them well suited for [developing](http://wolfram.com/xid/0ftssdy-gbblcn) distribution-specific quadrature rules

Comment: @Sasha: I'm actually working with [Askey-Wilson class polynomials](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.28), as well as $q$-analogs of classical orthogonal polynomials, for one of my personal projects. I know about being able to use `QHypergeometricPFQ[]`, but it seems that even a recursive definition can sometimes go a bit faster than using that. But yeah, even the humble Charlier polynomial is fascinating! :)

Comment: Can you give an update of any of the functions available in versions up to 11.1 provide more orthogonal polynomial other that the classic ones?

Comment: @Jose, I don't think anything new came up after version 6.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Yes, there is, although the speed-up is not as dramatic as for 1D memoization:

```
ClearAll[CharlierC];
CharlierC[0, a_, x_] := 1;
CharlierC[1, a_, x_] := x - a;
CharlierC[n_Integer, a_, x_] :=
  Module[{al, xl},
    Set @@ Hold[CharlierC[n, al_, xl_],          
        Expand[(xl - al - n + 1) CharlierC[n - 1, al, xl] - 
             al (n - 1) CharlierC[n - 2, al, xl]
        ]];
    CharlierC[n, a, x]
];
```

*(Thanks to @Mike Bantegui for pointing out the wastefulness of `Simplify`, which has now been removed).*
What you memoize here are function definitions.`Expand` is used to not accumulate the complexity too fast. The idea is that I first create a new *pattern-based* definition, using a number of tricks to fool the scoping variable - renaming mechanism but localize pattern variables, and then evaluate this definition.

For example:

```
In[249]:= CharlierC[20,a,x];//Timing
Out[249]= {0.063,Null}

In[250]:= CharlierC[25,a,x];//Timing
Out[250]= {0.078,Null}
```

While with clear definitions:

```
In[260]:= CharlierC[25,a,x];//Timing
Out[260]= {0.094,Null}
```

Here are a first few generated definitions:

```
In[262]:= Take[DownValues[CharlierC],4]
Out[262]= 
{HoldPattern[CharlierC[0,a_,x_]]:>1,
 HoldPattern[CharlierC[1,a_,x_]]:>x-a,
 HoldPattern[CharlierC[2,al$4106_,xl$4106_]]:>
      al$4106^2-xl$4106-2 al$4106 xl$4106+xl$4106^2,
 HoldPattern[CharlierC[3,al$4105_,xl$4105_]]:>
   -al$4105^3+2 xl$4105+3 al$4105 xl$4105+3 al$4105^2 xl$4105
       -3 xl$4105^2-3 al$4105 xl$4105^2+xl$4105^3}
```

Comment: I timed both versions, and yours is significantly slower on my machine. 0.016 seconds (mine) vs 1.185 seconds (yours) for n = 20. Still, very cool idea you have.

Comment: @Mike My code creates definitions for absolutely arbitrary `a`. Also, some time is spent on `Expand` and `Simplify`. It is slow the first run, but instant all the following runs. If your task is to vary `a` (say, plot when a is in some range), I only need to compute stuff once, and it will work for every value of `a`. If there is a single numerical `a`, then your code wins, but then arguably `a` is a constant rather than a true function argument, so the memoization is effectively 1D.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: If you want to vary a and x, you can simply evaluate it and attach it to a variable: `poly = CharlierC[100, a, x]` and then evaluate it for any arbitrary {a, x}. You just have to be careful to only evaluate `CharlierC[n, a, x]` for sybmolic a and x for my version, and always attach it to something beforehand.

Comment: I also deal with polynomials with more than three arguments, like the [Hahn polynomials](http://dlmf.nist.gov/18.19), and I expect to be varying indices and parameters a lot. So, Leonid's proposal seems to be most expedient for me.

Comment: @Mike Good point, I will edit. `Simplify` was taking the most time, I should have tried `Expand` alone. As to your first point: since in my case you compute all the previous ones in the process, you need almost no time to compute say `CharlierC[101, a, x]` fully symbolically then.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin: Just for the record, the way you did this is very cool and borderline black magic.

Comment: @Mike Thanks! I came up with this first about 5 years ago, when I needed it to compute functions with a huge number of terms. In those days, I wouldn't make a mistake with `Simplify`, but I got rusty since I quit Physics  :)

Comment: @Mike Well, I'd keep that, but as you wish of course.

Answer (score 27):

Nice question.  This is my suggested implementation.  Evaluate all code at once.

```
Clear[CharlierC, "CharlierC`*"]

CharlierC (* create symbol in current context *)

Begin["CharlierC`"];

implementation[0] := 1;
implementation[1] := x - a;
implementation[n_Integer] := 
 implementation[n] = Expand[(x - a - n + 1) implementation[n - 1] - 
                            a (n - 1) implementation[n - 2] ]

CharlierC[n_Integer ? NonNegative, ai_, xi_] := 
 Block[{a, x}, implementation[n] /. {a -> ai, x -> xi}]

End[];
```

The `Block` isn't strictly necessary as `a` and `x` are already created in the `` CharlierC` `` context where they should be safe.

This function memoizes the symbolic representation of `CharlierC` only, and only for each `n` (not `a` and `x`).  Then substitutes in whatever variables or numbers you pass in.

Comment: Now let me look at the other answers which I didn't check on purpose before posting (so the fun won't be spoiled!)

Comment: +1. This is simpler than what I suggested. Andy Ross did the first step just like you, but did not do replacements and deleted his answer, which is a pity. I only later realized that his (and now yours) code is no less general than mine, and perhaps also faster.

Comment: @Leonid My code is much slower than yours, but it is not completely clear to me why.  There was also a new, pure function based solution posted today.  Now it seems so obvious that pure functions are the simplest solution here ...

Comment: @Leonid My code was so slow because of the wrong placing of `Expand`, corrected now.

Comment: I see. That new solution is nice indeed. It did not cross my mind to use pure functions here.

Answer (score 23):

I would also suggest to use pure functions here:

```
CharlierC[0] = 1 &;
CharlierC[1] = #2 - #1 &;
CharlierC[n_Integer] := (CharlierC[n] = 
    Evaluate[
      Expand[(#2 - #1 - n + 1) CharlierC[n - 1][#1, #2] - #1 (n - 
           1) CharlierC[n - 2][#1, #2]]] &);
CharlierC[20][a, x] // AbsoluteTiming

(* ==> {0.0312414, 
 a^20 - 121645100408832000 x - 128047474114560000 a x - 
  67580611338240000 a^2 x - 23851980472320000 a^3 x - 
  6335682312960000 a^4 x - 1351612226764800 a^5 x - 
  241359326208000 a^6 x - 37132204032000 a^7 x - 
  5028319296000 a^8 x - 609493248000 a^9 x - 67044257280 a^10 x - 
  6772147200 a^11 x - 634888800 a^12 x - ...
*)
```

I haven't made comparisons, but this seems to be faster.

Comment: The disadvantage with this solution is that it memoizes for the second argument as well (`a`).  If we evaluate `CharlierC[5,a]`, the cached intermediate results can't be used by `CharlierC[5,b]`.  I think it should be possible to fix this.  Can you update the solution?

Comment: Done :-) Is it okay now?

Comment: +1, great solution!  But to nitpick a bit more, `Evaluate` is not needed in `CharlierC[1] = Evaluate[#2 - #1] &`  I placed `Expand` at the wrong position in my solution which caused a serious performance problem.  I corrected it now.

Comment: Yes, I've forgotten to remove this from the previous version.

Comment: Nice code - +1.

Answer (score 17):

You can utilize Dynamic Programming in the following way:

```
CharlierC[0, a_, x_] := 1
CharlierC[1, a_, x_] := x - a
CharlierC[n_Integer, a_, x_] := CharlierC[n, a, x] = Expand[Expand[(x - a - n + 1) CharlierC[n - 1, a, x]] - Expand[a (n - 1) CharlieC[n - 2, a, x]]]
```

It basically creates an in-memory store of previous evaluated function values instead of evaluating it every time you call it.

Mind you, if you actually tried evaluating CharlierC[50, a, x] it would still take a very long time. That's a very long polynomial you're trying to evaluate.

---

**Update**

The addition of the `Expand[..]` forces Mathematica to expand and combine like terms. It's actually possible to evaluate CharlierC[50, a, x].

If you wanted to really use that expression, here's how I would do it:

```
poly = CharlierC[50, a, x];

a = 0.01;
Plot[poly, {x, ...}];
```

Here's some timings. In between each run I did a `ClearAll` and evaluated the definition:

```
AbsoluteTiming[CharlierC[20, a, x];] (* 0.0250014 *)
AbsoluteTiming[CharlierC[40, a, x];] (* 0.1510087 *)
AbsoluteTiming[CharlierC[60, a, x];] (* 0.5150295 *)
```

What I would recommend is combining the ideas that Leonid and I have:

```
ClearAll[CharlierC];
CharlierC[0, a_, x_] := 1;
CharlierC[1, a_, x_] := x - a;
CharlierC[n_Integer, a_, x_] := Module[{al, xl},
   Set @@ Hold[CharlierC[n, al_, xl_],
     Expand[
      Expand[(xl - al - n + 1) CharlierC[n - 1, al, xl]] - 
       Expand[al (n - 1) CharlierC[n - 2, al, xl]]
      ]
     ];
   CharlierC[n, a, x]];
```

The use of `Expand` works much faster than `Simplify`.

Comment: Okay, try executing `CharlierC[10, 3, 1]` and subsequently `?CharlierC`. Messy, no? Using that version of `CharlierC[]` within something like `Plot[]` will make things worse.

Comment: I did actually use `Expand` in my initial answer as well - it was Simplify which was slow. And, you only need a single top-level one I think - I also just made an edit. But, again, thanks for your point, and +1.

Answer (score 1):

Decided to add one more version: what happened is that my question [How to memoize with patterns?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230533/35000) has been marked as a duplicate of this one, which I agree to. However I believe there are more general situations where it should work. I believe my version covers them.

```
toPatterns[x_] := 
 x /. Map[# -> Pattern[#, _] &, 
   Union@Select[Level[x, {-1}], Head[#] === Symbol &]]
ClearAll[myCharlierC]
myCharlierC[0, a_, x_] := 1;
myCharlierC[1, a_, x_] := x - a;
myCharlierC[n_Integer, a_, x_] := 
  myCharlierC[n, toPatterns[a], toPatterns[x]] = 
   Expand[(x - a - n + 1) myCharlierC[n - 1, a, 
       x] - (n - 1) a  myCharlierC[n - 2, a, x]];
```