# recursive integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, recursion, convolution

I am trying to do multiple integrations recursively. For instance, I would like to do the following equation for arbitrary integer $n$:

$\displaystyle R_n(t) = \int_0^t \mathrm dt' R_0(t-t') R_{n-1}(t')$

where $R_0(t) = e^{-k t}\cos\omega_0 t$. I can do it by brute force, but I would like to be able to do it automatically for any $n$.

Comment: As this is a convolution, might I ask why you aren't trying to use the [convolution theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_theorem)?

Comment: Another question related to recursive integrals is: [Solving a Volterra integral equation numerically](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/4677/245)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
ClearAll[r];
r[0, t_] := Exp[-k*t]*Cos[t];
r[n_, t_] := Integrate[r[0, t - td]*r[n - 1, td], {td, 0, t}]
```

eg

```
r[2,t]

(*
(\[ExponentialE]^(-k t) (2 \[ExponentialE]^(k t) k^2 - 
   k (2 k + t + k^2 t) Cos[t] + (k - k^3 + t + k^2 t) Sin[t]))/(2 (1 +
    k^2)^2)
*)
```

Comment: An interesting way to speed this up **considerably** is to avoid the *definite* integrals by doing this: `r[n_, t_] := Simplify[Subtract @@ Table[Integrate[r[0, t - td]*r[n - 1, td], td] /. td -> i, {i, {t, 0}}]`. It seems that by doing the indefinite integral first, I can circumvent additional convergence checks or simplifications that slow things down. But I'm surprised by how much faster it gets, e.g., for `r[4,t]`.

Comment: @Jens thanks; strange that it speeds it up so much. Do you mind if I add this piece of information to the answer?

Comment: Of course you can add it to the answer!

Answer (score 10):

As already mentioned, this is a convolution. Luckily, there's a more natural function to use for this problem than `Integrate[]`, and that function is called, appropriately enough, [`Convolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Convolve.html). Now, since `Convolve[]` assumes an infinite integration region, we need a `UnitStep[]` multiplier in both the functions being convolved to limit the integration region to a finite interval. Here is one such implementation, making use of `Convolve[]`, as well as a caching technique described [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53):

```
r[0, k_, t_] := Exp[-k t] Cos[t];
r[n_Integer, k_, t_] := 
  Module[{kl, tl, y}, 
   Set @@ Hold[r[n, kl_, tl_], 
     Simplify[
      Convolve[UnitStep[y] r[n - 1, kl, y], UnitStep[y] r[0, kl, y], 
       y, tl], tl >= 0]];
   r[n, k, t]];
```

Note that I had already taken the liberty to add `k` as an additional parameter. You can do the same thing for the $\omega_0$ factor within the cosine. The advantage of using Leonid's version of caching is that effort expended for computing, say, `r[10, 4, t]` is still usable for computing `r[7, 8, t]`, since the caching remembers for a generic, as opposed to a specific, `k` value.

Answer (score 3):

You can write the definition down like that in *Mathematica*:

```
r[0, t_] := Exp[-k t] Cos[ω0 t]
r[n_, t_] := r[n, t] = 
    Integrate[r[0, t - tt] r[n - 1, tt], {tt, 0, t}, 
              Assumptions -> k > 0 && ω0 > 0]
```

... or is that what you considered to be brute force, and you're looking for a general solution of the recursion relation?

Anyway, the code above is awfully slow, even though I used the `r := r =` trick. It gets much faster when setting $k$ and $\omega_0$ to $1$.

Comment: Try `Expand` before `Integrate` for a moderate speedup.

Comment: what is the r:=r= trick doing? why is it speeding things up? PS how do I 'grey' text when commenting?

Comment: @BeauGeste the `r[t_] := r[t] =` trick is called memoization. Essentially, it saves the result of `r[t]` at the value of `t` for later look-up. (This exploits the [difference between `OwnValues` and `DownValues`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127/52) in the evaluation loop.)

Comment: @BeauGeste the greyed out text is just using the shorthand code markup, i.e. wrap the code in ` to get it greyed out.