# Solving Fredholm Equation of the first kind

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I want to numerically solve [Fredholm integral equations of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation), equations of the form

$$g(t)=\int_a^b K(t,s)f(s)\,\mathrm{d}s$$

where we know the functions $K(t,s)$ and $g(t)$ and seek to find $f(s)$. I'm aware of some papers presenting numerical methods (e.g. [1](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2949679)) but have not found any Mathematica implementations for what appears to be a reasonably standard problem.

Comment: The approaches described here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/solving-a-volterra-integral-equation-numerically should help.

Comment: I defer to the mathematicians in the group, but the Volterra integral
equation mentioned in the duplicate question is a Fredholm integral
equation of the second kind, and of special convolution form. That
equation has an unknown left-hand side which also appears under the
integral. The Fredholm integral equation of the first kind in this
question has a known left-hand side which does not appear under the
integral, and is not explicitly of convolution form. Duplicate?

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the reference provided by @MikeHoneychurch, your question about
seeking $f(s)$ given the moments or projections or linear combinations $g(t)$,
falls into the same category as
[this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26336/how-to-perform-a-multi-peak-fitting/26338)
question about multi-peak fitting. There, the $f(s)$ are Gaussian-like shapes.

Are you working with discrete samplings of the data $g(t)$? or are you looking
for theoretical, continuous forms of $g(t)$?

If discrete, then the integral equation may be transformed to a matrix system
by partitioning the $s$-axis into discrete intervals. The function $f(s)$ may be
represented on the partitioned $s$-axis as a comb of delta-functions, or narrow
rectangular shapes, or other form. Finding the integrals with the known kernel
functions $K(t,s)$ generates a matrix system $A\cdot x=b$. Mathematica has many built-in
functions for solving discrete system, with and without constraints.

I have been working with such equations for many years, especially for systems
where $x$ is non-negative. The book, Solving Least Squares Problems, and
[fortran code](http://netlib.org/lawson-hanson/all) by Lawson and Hanson may be useful. Michael Woodhams implemented a key routine, NNLS, in Mathematica
[here](http://forums.wolfram.com/mathgroup/archive/2003/Oct/msg00053.html).
The paper by Istratov and Vyvenko (Exponential analysis in physical phenomena.
Rev. Sci. Instrum. 70(2), 1233 (1999)) is a good review of techniques.