# Solving a Volterra integral equation

Tags: numerical-integration, integral-equations

I review this question [Solving a Volterra integral equation numerically.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/solving-a-volterra-integral-equation-numerically)
But I can not understand that.
I have the following code:

```
u[1][x_] = (-k)*(E^(Pi*x) + x); 
u[2][x_] = Refine[Integrate[(x - t)*E^u[1][t], {t, 0, x}], E^(Pi*x) >= 0]
```

`K` is constant.  Any suggestions analytical or numerical?

Comment: Could you expand on the reasons why the three approaches proposed in the linked question don't work for you? Perhaps that might restrict the question and encourage answers.

Comment: @MarcoB  I can not understand that. I corrected the question.

Comment: What exactly is the Volterra equation you wish to solve? Is it `u[x] == Integrate[(x - t)*E^u[t], {t, 0, x}]`? Whatever it is, it should be given explicitly in the question.