# Why does Expand not work within a function?

Tags: function-construction, special-functions, polynomials

I'm writing this fairly simple function:

```
hermite[0, x] = 1;
hermite[1, x] = 2 x;
hermite[n_, x_] := (
  hermite[n, x] = 2 x*hermite[n - 1, x] - 2 (n - 1) hermite[n - 2, x];
  Expand[hermite[n, x]]
  )
```

But the `Expand` command is ignored.

Yet, when I do

```
Expand[hermite[10, x]]
```

The result is expanded like I wish.

Why is it not working when I put the same command inside a function? I'd like to do it in the function; it would be cleaner.

Comment: You forgot the underscore after x in the first two definitions. Now, these functions only work if you provide them with the symbol x as argument. Overall I'd say this is a bit messy definition. I have no Mathematica at hand at the moment, but I think the second time you evaluate this with the same arguments you already have stored a definition for these arguments which is then executed and you'll never get to the Expand. It looks like you have been incorrectly modifying a *memoizing* definition of hermite.

Comment: Audrey, you might want to take a look at [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53), which gives better methods for implementing multiparameter recursive functions.

Answer (score 14):

To implement what you intended to do, I suggest to take a look at this approach :

```
hermite[0, x_] := 1
hermite[1, x_] := 2 x
hermite[n_Integer /; n >= 2, x_] :=
    hermite[n, x] = Expand[2 x*hermite[n - 1, x] - 2 (n - 1) hermite[n - 2, x]]
```

Now you shouldn't have problems anymore.

Recalling that there are in `Mathematica` the Hermite polynomials $H_{n}(x)$  since the version 1, namely `HermiteH` function, we can check if the above is correctly implemented :

```
And @@ SameQ @@@ ({hermite[#, x], HermiteH[#, x]} & /@ Range[100])
```

> ```
> True
> ```

e.g.

```
hermite[10, x]
```

> ```
> -30240 + 302400 x^2 - 403200 x^4 + 161280 x^6 - 23040 x^8 + 1024 x^10
> ```

The problem with your approach appears with so-called [memoization](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/FunctionsThatRememberValuesTheyHaveFound.html) of

```
2 x*hermite[n - 1, x] - 2 (n - 1) hermite[n - 2, x]
```

but not `Expand[hermite[n, x]]`, so there you had i.e.

```
hermite[5, x]
```

> ```
> 2 x (12 - 48 x^2 + 16 x^4) - 8 (-8 x + 2 x (-2 + 4 x^2))
> ```

instead of

> ```
> 120 x - 160 x^3 + 32 x^5
> ```

We solved the problem by remembering

```
Expand[ 2 x*hermite[n - 1, x] - 2 (n - 1) hermite[n - 2, x] ]
```

To avoid another possible problems with the variable `n`, I included a condition in the definition of `hermite[n, x]`. In your approach you had i.e. `hermite[1, x] = 2 x;` and so evaluating i.e.

```
Plot[{hermite[0, x], hermite[1, x]}, {x, -5, 5}]     (* A *)
```

a message is generated `$RecursionLimit::reclim` of  exceeded `$RecursionLimit` (by default its value is `256`). To avoid this problem you have do this :

```
 Plot[ Evaluate @ {hermite[0, x], hermite[1, x]}, {x, -5, 5}]  (* B *)
```

With my approach you needn't evaluate the functions, so you can choose (* A *).

Answer (score 6):

For me, both return the same result. Quit the kernel and restart or, use

```
ClearAll[hermite]
hermite[0, x] = 1;
hermite[1, x] = 2 x;
hermite[n_,x_] := 
   (hermite[n, x] =  2 x*hermite[n - 1, x] - 2 (n - 1) hermite[n - 2, x];
    Expand[hermite[n, x]]
   )
```

As suggested in the comments here is the version you are likely after:

```
ClearAll[hermite]
hermite[0, x] = 1;
hermite[1, x] = 2 x;
hermite[n_, x_] := 
 hermite[n, x] = 
  Expand[2 x*hermite[n - 1, x] - 2 (n - 1) hermite[n - 2, x]]
```

In the comments it was suggested to mention that in functions that have attribute `Hold` you are better of to call `Evaluate` as in

```
Plot[Evaluate[{hermite[0, x], hermite[1, x]}], {x, -5, 5}]
```

to avoid recursion.

Comment: oh, right, thanks.

Comment: By memoizing the *unexpanded* version of `hermite` you create a subtle bug.  E.g, the first call to `hermite[3, x]` returns the expanded version `-12 x + 8 x^3` whereas all subsequent calls will return the *unexpanded* version `-8 x + 2 x (-2 + 4 x^2)`.  The solution, of course, is to change the order of operations so that the the expanded version is stored.

Comment: @Artes, what exactly is defective?

Comment: Haven't you got any messages `$RecursionLimit::reclim` ? Here it luckily works, even with them, but in general it is not recommended, e.g. for taking too much memory.

Comment: @Artes, no, no messages for me.

Comment: Maybe you have switched off any messages ?

Comment: @Artes, no. If you are talking about your plot commad (why do I need to read your post to understand comments on this one? You could have mentioned that) you need to evaluate the expr as in `Plot[Evaluate[{hermite[0, x], hermite[1, x]}], {x, -5, 5}]`

Comment: @ruebenko Ok it works, but it would be reasonable to add a comment on this in the post. I'm deleting my comments on the problem and +1.