# Get polynomial interpolation formula

Tags: interpolation, polynomials, memoization

I'm attempting to get a polynomial interpolation formula out of `Mathematica` but I am absolutely lost. I stared out using `Wolfram|Alpha`, but it seems as if my input had become too large.

I tried using this on `WolframAlpha.com` :

```
Interpolate {1,33},{2,80},{5,286},{10,771},{15,1382},{20,2087},{25,2867},{30,3707},{40,5526},
{50,7470},{60,9482},{70,11507},{80,13495},{90,15391},{100,17313},{110,18631},{120,19752},
{125,20064}
```

but I get an error.

Thinking that `Mathematica` was the solution I signed up for a trial but I can't seem to get an interpolation formula out of it. Searching Google and this exchange has given me very few results.

Any idea how I can just get a polynomial interpolation formula from my dataset?

Comment: Have you tried using the Documentation Center under the Help menu? I found the answer in there, but I'd like to know you've done a little searching yourself, first.

Comment: Once you write out the equations for coefficients of the polynomial, it becomes a linear algebra problem with a vandermonde matrix http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html?q=LinearSolve&lang=en Or you can use the documentation center and search for Interpolation.

Comment: To clarify: do you want to do an interpolation, or a regression? PlatoManiac's answer shows both routes.

Comment: @rcollyer I did do some searching on my own using Google and ended up on the Mathematica online help. The results I got to though didn't give me what I was looking for.I was confused because I couldn't just get a straight forward formula like I could on Wolframalpha. From the responses below it seems more involved and when I felt I was in over my head I decided to ask.

Comment: @J.M. I believe I want interpolation... I have a set of values and would like to get the best guess of the ranges in between those values.

Comment: @BOMEz a useful and necessary skill is to be able to search within the documentation itself, and not via google. Obviously, you know the answer now, but try searching for "interpolating polynomial" in the documentation center and see what you get. I got to it by going through `InterpolationFunction` and seeing the related functions.

Comment: As already noted by some of the answers, an interpolating polynomial might not necessarily be the best idea. You might want to look at a *piecewise* interpolating polynomial, for which *Mathematica* has the `Interpolation[]` function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First take your data

```
data = {{1, 33}, {2, 80}, {5, 286}, {10, 771}, {15, 1382}, {20, 
2087}, {25, 2867}, {30, 3707}, {40, 5526}, {50, 7470}, {60, 
9482}, {70, 11507}, {80, 13495}, {90, 15391}, {100, 17313}, {110, 
18631}, {120, 19752}, {125, 20064}};
```

Then we call `LinearModelFit` and fit a cubic polynomial to your data.

```
lm = LinearModelFit[data, {x^3, x^2, x}, x];
Show[ListPlot[data, PlotStyle -> Red,Filling->Bottom],Plot[lm[x],{x, 0, 125}],Frame -> True]
```

[image]

And to get the polynomial that best fits your data.

```
Normal[lm]
```

> -83.6419 + 69.7325 x + 2.19787 x^2 - 0.0116981 x^3

Now you must realize that above polynomial is not an interpolation of your data but a best continuous approximation of it with respect to the Euclidean norm. Forming a interpolating polynomial for a data of $n$ points require at least a $n$-th degree polynomial. This is not practical as higher degree polynomials come with higher and unwanted oscillations. Hence people use polynomials for peace-wise interpolation. `HermitePolynomil` can be used for this purpose.

But if you want you can get an interpolating polynomial for your data as follows.

```
InterpolatingPolynomial[data, x] // Expand // N
```

> 3.1289 + 18.9719 x + 12.41 x^2 - 1.71825 x^3 + 0.228052 x^4 - 
>    0.0219672 x^5 + 0.00150955 x^6 - 0.0000751269 x^7 + 
>    2.75112*10^-6 x^8 - 7.49912*10^-8 x^9 + 1.53098*10^-9 x^10 - 
>    2.34119*10^-11 x^11 + 2.66291*10^-13 x^12 - 2.216*10^-15 x^13 + 
>    1.30841*10^-17 x^14 - 5.18423*10^-20 x^15 + 1.2348*10^-22 x^16 - 
>    1.33508*10^-25 x^17

You can see the above polynomial has degree 17 and you have 18 data entries. This interpolating polynomial also fails to keep up with the data trend. You can see this phenomena in the boundaries of the following plot. For $x$ outside your data range the mammoth polynomial (dashed one) starts to disagree with given data trend almost exponentially! The approximating cubic polynomial (thick red one) captures the data behavior very well even beyond the given data range.

[image]

Comment: A linear fit is not guaranteed to go through every point, but an interpolating polynomial is. So, while this answer a question, it is not the same one as asked.

Comment: @rcollyer thanks for pointing out! I tried to modify the answer..

Comment: @PlatoManiac I suggest deleting the `LinearModelFit` part, as it could be misleading for future readers

Answer (score 8):

You may want [a quick sketch](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11350/xkcd-style-graphs) :)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or, you could also solve the [Vandermonde matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde_matrix):

```
n = 10;(* points number*)
{xi, yi} = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2, n}];
a = LinearSolve[Transpose@Table[xi^k, {k, 0, n - 1}], yi]

(* System solved, now plot it *)
p[x_, m_] := Sum[a[[i + 1]] x^i, {i, 0, m}];
Show[Plot[p[x, n - 1], {x, 0, 1},  PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-20, 20}}], 
     ListPlot[Transpose[{xi, yi}], PlotStyle -> {PointSize[Medium], Red}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just be aware that it may, depending on your points, results in an ill-conditioned system

Comment: ...or, one could use the (undocumented) function `LinearAlgebra\`VandermondeSolve[]`.

Comment: @J.M. _One_ could only if _one_ knows it :) . Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Evaluating what the OP tried with free-form input (shortcut `=`) yields a suggestion cell with this input :  `Expand[ InterpolatingPolynomial[{286, 771}, x]]`, similarly a `Wolfram|Alpha` query yields input interpretation `interpolating polynomial`, so it is not especially difficult to surmise that the desired function is [`InterpolatingPolynomial`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html?q=InterpolatingPolynomial&lang=en). Defining the list `l` :

```
l = {{1, 33}, {2, 80}, {5, 286}, {10, 771}, {15, 1382}, {20, 2087}, {25, 2867}, {30, 3707},
     {40, 5526}, {50, 7470}, {60, 9482}, {70, 11507}, {80, 13495}, {90, 15391}, {100, 17313},
     {110, 18631}, {120, 19752}, {125, 20064}};
```

the resulting polynomial (written in a standard expanded form ) is :

```
p[x_] := Expand @ InterpolatingPolynomial[ l, x]
```

### How could we define an interpolating polynomial having no `InterpolatingPolynomial` built-in function ?

A natural way is to define recursively a family of polynomials. In order to make it possibly fast we can take advantage of memoization techiques (see e.g. answers to [What is “x := x =” trickery?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-is-x-x-trickery) or [Why does Expand not work within a function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/why-does-expand-not-work-within-a-function) )

```
poly[x_, 0]  := l[[1, 2]]
poly[x_, k_] := poly[ x, k] = poly[ x, k-1] + 
               (l[[k, 2]] - poly[l[[k, 1]], k-1]) Product[(x-l[[j, 1]])/(l[[k, 1]]-l[[j, 1]]),
                                                           {j, k - 1}]
```

let's check if it works properly :

```
Expand @ poly[ x, Length @ l] === p[x]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Well indeed, now we  can imagine what is behind  `InterpolatingPolynomial` so let's restrict to `p[x]` being a seventeenth order polynomial with rational coefficients (in general when the list is of length `n` then the polynomial will be of order `n-1`, and if `l` is a list of rational pairs, `p` will be a polynomial with  rational coefficients).  One can reproduce the list `l` with `p[x]` :

```
p[#] & /@ l[[All, 1]] == l[[All, 2]]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Since its coefficients are a bit involved we prefer to write them this way :

```
p[x] // TraditionalForm // N
```

[image]

```
Plot[ p[x], {x, -12, 128}, PlotStyle -> Thick, Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.01], Point[l]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The output of `InterpolatingPolynomial[]` is in **[Newton form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton_polynomial)**, not Horner form.

Comment: @J.M. according to the [docs](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/InterpolatingPolynomial.html) (4th under more info) the polynomial is output in Horner form so that it is suitable for numerical evaluation. So, however it generates the polynomial, and I suspect that it is Newton-Cotes, it rearranges it into Horner's form.

Comment: @rcollyer, the docs are wrong, then. Compare `InterpolatingPolynomial[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {p, q}, {r, s}}, x]` and `HornerForm[InterpolatingPolynomial[{{a, b}, {c, d}, {p, q}, {r, s}}, x], x]`. Horner form is nothing but the special case of the Newton form, when all the interpolation points coalesce. It looks like Horner, but it's not really Horner.

Comment: BTW @rcollyer: "Netwon-Cotes" is the name used for the series of integration rules based on interpolating polynomials on equispaced points; Newton (divided difference) interpolation (which is what `InterpolatingPolynomial[]` does) is a whole 'nother thing altogether...

Comment: @J.M. I must disagree. Newton is written as a sum being a linear combination of polynomials. While debating the content of wikipedia is often pointless, your link does not show anything near Horner's form. While `InterpolatingPolynomial` doesn't return what we'd precisely call Horner's form, it is a generalization that I have not seen associated with Newton, so I'd call it Horner's form, or generalized Horner's, if I'm being pedantic. And, yes, I mis-remembered Newton-Cotes.

Comment: @rcollyer: Well, have a look [here](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=Mp8-z5mHptcC&pg=PA168) and [here](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=x69Q226WR8kC&pg=PA331). I'm away from my books, so I am unable to give other examples... the numbers in the Newton form corresponding to the coefficients in the Horner form are precisely the divided differences, so I would say it is fine to say the polynomial is in Newton form.

Comment: @J.M. You're first reference, I think makes my overall point. It is at best a generalized Horner's, and referring to it as Newton's confuses the issue. I think the docs made the correct choice in how to describe it. It could use the word generalized added to it to avoid any confusion, but not strictly necessary.