# Determine Functions Given Data Points

Tags: equation-solving

Is it possible for Mathematica to solve for f(x,y) = 0
such that {x,y} contains `{{0,0.5}, {1,0.5}, {0.6,0.8}, {0.4,0.2}}`  ?

Do we need to specify f(x,y) first ?

Thank you

Comment: The constant function `f[x,y]=0` contains those solution, and is found by mathematica using InterpolatingPolynomial: `InterpolatingPolynomial[{{{0, 0.5}, 0}, {{1, 0.5}, 0}, {{0.6, 0.8}, 0}, {{0.4, 0.2}, 0}}, {x, y}]`

Comment: There are infinitely many such functions, even among polynomials. This is in fact a duplicate of [Get polynomial interpolation formula](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/get-polynomial-interpolation-formula). I recommend taking a closer look at [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/get-polynomial-interpolation-formula/11799#11799).