# Generating a polynomial that's accurate to within an error of no more than 1/10^5

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, polynomials, homework, approximation

I'm currently stuck on a question for class that asks...

"Find a polynomial `p[x]` that you can use to calculate
`6 ArcTan[x]` 
to within an error of no more than `10^(-5)` for all the x's with `-(1/Sqrt[3]) <= x <= 1/Sqrt[3]`."

I used a series expansion below.

```
Clear[x];   
approx6arctan[x_] = Normal[Series[6Tan[x], {x, 0, 200}]]
```

However, this can only generate a function that's accurate only to the fourth decimal, no matter how much I expand the series (200 is already huge).

Any hints on how to generate a polynomial that's accurate to the fifth decimal? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have typed `Tan` instead of `ArcTan`.

Comment: See also: `Plot[{approx6arctan[x],ArcTan[x]},{x,-Pi,Pi}]`

Comment: This link about [Chebyshev polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev_polynomials) might be useful.

Answer (score 14):

From [Weierstrass Approximation Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem) we know there is such a polynomial, moreover there are infinitely many polynomials satisfying  given criterion. Therefore we would like to find those ones of the minimal order.

Since we are supposed to exploit series approximations we define a polynomial of `n` - th order approximating `6 ArcTan[x]` for `x` such that `(-(1/Sqrt[3]) <= x <= 1/Sqrt[3])` with the `10^(-5)` accuracy. We can use a Taylor series of the given function:

```
poly[x_, n_Integer] /; n > 0 := Normal @ Series[ 6 ArcTan[x], { x, 0, n}]
```

Next we would like to minimize the "error" function like the following:

```
Abs[ poly[x, n] - 6 ArcTan[x]]
```

We could proceed further with symbolic functions however numeric ones can be much faster thus we can use `NMaximize` with the constraint `-(1/Sqrt[3]) <= x <= 1/Sqrt[3]`:

```
NMaximize[{ Abs[poly[x, n] - 6 ArcTan[x]], -(1/Sqrt[3]) <= x <= 1/Sqrt[3]}, x]
```

Finally we can exploit the new function in *Mathematica 10* `SelectFirst`:

```
SelectFirst[ 
  Table[{ n, First @ NMaximize[{ Abs[poly[x, n] - 6 ArcTan[x]], 
                                -(1/Sqrt[3]) <= x <= 1/Sqrt[3]}, x]}, {n, 4, 20}],
  Last[#] < 10^-5 &]
```

> ```
> {17, 7.12022*10^-6}
> ```

So the minimal order polynomial is

```
poly[x, 17]
```

> ```
> 6 x - 2 x^3 + (6 x^5)/5 - (6 x^7)/7 + (2 x^9)/3 - (6 x^11)/11 
>  + (6 x^13)/13 - (2 x^15)/5 + (6 x^17)/17
> ```

much lower order than you expected.

**Edit**

We have exploited Taylor series solutions, now we can optimize approximations based on another tools *Mathematica* can offer.

Another answer introduced `LeastSquarePolynomial` providing quite a good approximation however in case of more general functions or if better approximations are needed that might appear to be too computationally complex since it involves symbolic integration.
 Therefore alternative approach is welcome. We provide another solution based on a simple algebraic functionality `InterpolatingPolynomial` (see e.g. this answer [Get polynomial interpolation formula](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/get-polynomial-interpolation-formula/11799#11799) for an idea how it works)

```
intpoly[x_, n_] := 
    Collect[
      InterpolatingPolynomial[
        Table[ {x, 6 ArcTan[x]}, {x, -1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3], 1/(n Sqrt[3])}], x],
      x, Simplify]
```

Now this polynomial also satisfies conditions:

```
intpoly[x, 5] // N // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Now let's compare graphically various approximations:

```
Plot[{ 6 ArcTan[x] - intpoly[x, 5], 
       6 ArcTan[x] - poly, 
       6 ArcTan[x] - intpoly[x, 6]}, {x, -1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]}, 
     Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

and its absolute values:

```
Plot[{ Abs[6 ArcTan[x] - intpoly[x, 5]], 
       Abs[6 ArcTan[x] - poly], 
       Abs[6 ArcTan[x] - intpoly[x, 6]]}, {x, -1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]}, 
     Evaluated -> True, PlotStyle -> Thick, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

We can clearly see that

```
intpoly[x, 6] // N // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

wins that comparison with respect to accuracy while `intpoly[x, 5]` and `poly` are of the minimal order (`9`). However one could probably find even lower order polynomials satisfying the criterion.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response, Artes. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @user19060 I'm glad I could help. If you have found what you were looking for you should  accept the answer.  It is recommended to register your account to benefit more from using this site

Comment: `intpoly[x, 5]` extremely close to the polynomial I found, awesome! Also you said "one could probably find even lower order polynomials satisfying the criterion", but I don't think that's possible. Linear least squares finds the polynomial that minimizes the max error of `|f[x] - p[x]|` if I remember correctly.

Comment: @ChipHurst I believe it depends on what kind of norm in the appropriate function space we consider. I can't definitely say it is possible however `intpoly[x, 6]` is a considerably better approximation than `poly` while the latter is better than `intpoly[x, 5]`. So I have to say that `poly` is a really good one.

Comment: @Artes, where is `poly` defined? Do you mean `poly[x, 17]`?

Comment: @ChipHurst I referred to your `poly`.

Answer (score 11):

Taylor polynomials of order `n` aren't necessarily the `nth` degree polynomials that optimally approximate a function on a given interval.

We can use [linear least squares](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_(mathematics)) to find the optimal polynomials for a fixed `n`.

```
inn[f_, g_, x_] := Integrate[f g, {x, -1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]}]

LeastSquarePolynomial[f_, x_, n_] := With[{pows = x^Range[0, n]},
  pows . LinearSolve[Outer[inn[#1, #2, x] &, pows, pows], inn[f, #, x] & /@ pows]
]
```

By inspection `n == 9` is the first to achieve your desired error bound.

```
poly = LeastSquarePolynomial[6ArcTan[x], x, 9]

(* 693/256(94140Sqrt[3]π - 512251)x - 1287/16(135345Sqrt[3]π - 736466)x^3 + 11583/640(6901020Sqrt[3]π - 37551197)x^5 - 590733/224(200130Sqrt[3]π - 1088987)x^7 + 18706545/1792(70868Sqrt[3]π - 385621)x^9 *)

N[poly]

(* 5.99999x - 1.99942x^3 + 1.18912x^5 - 0.771597x^7 + 0.351287x^9 *)
```

Here's the error:

```
NMaximize[{Abs[6ArcTan[x] - %], -1/Sqrt[3] <= x <= 1/Sqrt[3]}, x]

(* {1.60527*10^-6, {x->-0.57735}} *)
```

and a plot

```
Plot[Abs[6ArcTan[x] - poly], {x, -1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Considering this is a homework problem for a calculus class, I suspect "polynomial" here refers to a Taylor polynomial and not polynomials derived by non-calculus methods like least-squares.

Answer (score 9):

We can find a 7th order polynomial that meets the requirement if we minimise the $\infty$-norm. For simplicity I construct an array of `{x, 6 ArcTan[x]}` over the required range and plug it into `FindFit`, no doubt there are better ways.

```
{a, b} = {-1, 1}/Sqrt[3];
data = Table[{x, 6 ArcTan[x]}, {x, a, b, (b - a)/1000.}];
n = 7;
expr = Sum[c[i] x^i, {i, 1, n, 2}];
pars = Table[c[i], {i, 1, n, 2}];

fit = expr /. FindFit[data, expr, pars, x, NormFunction -> (Norm[#, Infinity] & )]
```

> 5.99985 x - 1.99354 x^3 + 1.12458 x^5 - 0.510485 x^7

The maximum error is:

```
NMaxValue[{fit - 6 ArcTan[x], a <= x <= b}, x]
```

> 9.53823*10^-6

```
Plot[fit - 6 ArcTan[x], {x, a, b}, GridLines -> {None, {-10^-5, 10^-5}}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of answers to this question already, but allow me to suggest to take a look at `PadeApproximant` if you want to come up with a good approximation to `ArcTan[x]`:

```
Manipulate[
  Column[{
    Row[{"ArcTan[x] \[TildeTilde] ", approx = PadeApproximant[ArcTan[x], {x, 0, {m, n}}]}],
    Plot[Abs[(approx - ArcTan[x])/ArcTan[x]], {x, -1/Sqrt[3], 1/Sqrt[3]}, ImageSize -> Large, PlotLabel -> "Error"]
  }],
  {m, 1, 7, 1},
  {n, 1, 7, 1}
]
```

Comment: That generates a rational function and not a polynomial, tho. But Padé approximants certainly are nice.

Comment: Yes, that's why I posted this suggestion. I certainly wished I'd have learned about them much sooner than I actually did.