# Minimizing the largest difference between two functions

Tags: functions, function-construction, mathematical-optimization

I have two functions defined on the same domain, $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ where $x$ is in $(0,1)$:

```
f[x_] := (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] - x Log[x]
g[x_] := Log[1 + 2 (-1 + x) x]
```

I would like to find a constant $c$ such that the maximum of $f(x)-cg(x)$ is minimized on the domain $(0,1)$.

My first attempt was to try

```
Minimize[Maximize[{f[x]-c g[x],0<x<1},x],c]
```

but this just gives me back my input as the output.

Am I going about this the wrong way entirely? I feel like it's got something to do with the inner Maximize not evaluating because it's a function of more than one variable but I have no idea how to deal with this.

Comment: Without  defining your functions $f$ and $g$ how could the system find the minimum?  Nonetheless take a look at related problems e.g. [Generating a polynomial that's accurate to within an error of no more than 1/10^5](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57003/generating-a-polynomial-thats-accurate-to-within-an-error-of-no-more-than-1-10) and [Finding minimal distance between two surfaces](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/65847/finding-minimal-distance-between-two-surfaces).

Comment: My apologies, the functions are certainly defined but the question was more general, for any two given functions. A specific example has been edited in.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: You should  restrict `c` appropriately, even for these functions. However your question is still unclear. Do you want to minimize pointwise $f(x)-cg(x)$ or in a different norm?

Comment: In principle, there are no restrictions on $c$ other than it being real. I believe I wish to use a sup norm, but perhaps I am misunderstanding your comment?

Comment: Please see the result of `Plot[Maximize[{f@x - c g@x, 0 < x < 1}, x][[1]], {c, -5, 1}]`

Comment: And you should start your comments with `@usrname`, otherwise the other user isn't notified

Comment: @belisarius You can use `MaxValue` instead of `Maximize[[1]]` (seeing as you're going for brevity with `f@x` and all)

Comment: What about the sign of the difference `f[x]-c g[x] `?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before I begin, a quick note.  In the problem as stated, the optimal value of c is $-\infty$, since that makes the value of $f-(-\infty)g=f-\infty=-\infty$ (since $g<0$ for all $x\in(0,1)$).  I'll instead work the problem of minimizing $|f-cg|$.

First we can evaluate the `Maximize` statement, just to see what we get:

```
Maximize[{Abs[f[x] - c g[x]], 0 < x < 1}, x]
(* Maximize[{Abs[(-1 + x) Log[1 - x] - x Log[x] - 
c Log[1 + 2 (-1 + x) x]], 0 < x < 1}, x] *)
```

It appears that `Maximize` won't solve this subproblem, leaving `Minimize` nothing to work with.  However, we can get `Maximize` to evaluate if we give it a numerical value of `c`.  Let's define a helper function:

```
maxDiff[c_?NumericQ] := MaxValue[{Abs[f[x] - c g[x]], 0 < x < 1}, x]
```

Note the use of `NumericQ` to prevent this function from evaluating unless a number is passed to it.  Also, I'm using `MaxValue` instead of `Maximize` because `Maximize` produces a list contain both the maximum value and a list of rules describing the location of the maximum, where we only want the former.

We can now plot our function:

```
Plot[maxDiff[c], {c, -2, 0}]
```

[image]

... and see that it reaches a minimum at around $c=-1$.  We can now let `FindMinimum` loose:

```
FindMinimum[maxDiff[c], {c, -1}]
(* {0.098187, {c -> -1.14363}} *)
```

The sharp corner gives `FindMinimum` some trouble, as it expects a smooth function (we get a `FindMinimum::sdprec` message) but we can verify on the graph that the minimum was indeed found correctly.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It seems that ?NumericQ is the main ingredient I was missing. There's a lot of voodoo (for me) with Map/pure functions/Apply etc. which I found searching through related questions but this answer solved my problem perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I take it you are interested in the minimum in the absolute value of the difference `Abs[f[x]-c g[x]]`. Otherwise, the answer is trivial: `c=-Infinity`. 
Let us define the functions:

```
    f[x_] := (-1 + x) Log[1 - x] - x Log[x];
g[x_] := Log[1 + 2 (-1 + x) x];
w[x_, c_] := f[x] - c*g[x];
```

and plot them:

```
Manipulate[Plot[w[x, c], {x, 0, 1}], {c, -3, -0.1}]
```

yielding this: 
[image]
From playing with it it becomes clear that the minimum value of the function  `Abs[f[x]-c g[x]]` takes place somewhere at negative `c`between about -1.25 and -0.3, where there are three extremes, two of them being different. Or at least it looks like that. I did not check this, but you may make a check analogously to what is written below.
  Let us take this interval and determine the absolute maximum:

```
 lst = Table[{c, 
     Max[Abs[FindMaximum[w[x, c], {x, 0.1}][[1]]], 
      Abs[FindMinimum[w[x, c], {x, 0.45}][[1]]]]}, {c, -1.251, 0, 
     0.001}] // Quiet;

ListPlot[lst, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["c", 16, Italic], 
   Style["Max[Abs[w]]", 16, Italic]}]
```

returning this:

[image]

Now it is not difficult to find the point, where it is absolute minimum:

```
 lst[[Position[lst, Min[Transpose[lst][[2]]]][[1, 1]]]]

(*  {-1.142, 0.0985002}   *)
```

This may be at least one way of how practically to get the value.

Have fun!