# Approximation of the Fabius function with a quotient of exponentials

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, special-functions, approximation

**Approximation of the Fabius function $f(x) = \text{FabiusF}[x+1]\cdot \text{HeavisideTheta}[1-x^2]$ - FabiusF[x] doesn't work in Wolfram-Alpha**

I am looking to figure out how well the displaced version of the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) $f(x) = \text{FabiusF}[x+1],\quad |x|\leq 1$ could being approximated by the function:
$$g(x) = \frac{1+\exp\left(\frac{-1}{|x|^{\frac{3}{4}\sqrt{2\pi}}}\right)}{1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2\ |x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)}$$
but I don't have *Mathematica* and I use instead Wolfram-Alpha where the function [FabiusF[x]](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FabiusF/) is not working as you could see [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Fabius%5Bx%2B1%5D*HeavisideTheta%5B1-x%5E2%5D), so I would like to ask for help in order to **compare in a plot $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ for $x\in [-1,\ 1]$ (just a picture will work)**, and also if possible the plot of $f'(x)$ and $g'(x)$.

This is related to this other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4700782/909869), so if you want to improve it by changing some constants, you are also welcome. "Supposedly" $f(x)$ should fulfill $f'(x) = 2f(2x+1)-2f(2x-1)$ which is what I am trying to match in the approximation (or something "similar" like $f'(x) = k\left(f(2x+1)-f(2x-1)\right)$ for some $k \in \mathbb{R}$).

Thanks a lot beforehand.

[image: Desmos example]

---

**Added after the question was answered**

I have realized later that the following function:
$$q(x)=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)}$$
Matches "almost perfectly" the comstruction of a "smooth" transition curve show in Wikipedia [Non-analytic smooth function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-analytic_smooth_function):

1. Define $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x}},\quad x>0\\ 0,\quad x\leq 0\end{cases}$$
2. Define $$p(x)=\frac{f(x)}{f(x)+f(1-x)}$$
3. Then for some real valued constants $a<b<c<d$ one could built a [smooth bump function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bump_function) as: $$r(x)=p\left(\frac{x-a}{b-a}\right)\cdot p\left(\frac{d-x}{d-c}\right)$$ which is non-zero in $[a,\ d]$ such is flat on $[b,\ c]$

One can "experimentally" see that for $[a,\ d]\equiv [-1,\ 1]$, by chosing $b\to 0,\ c\to 0$ then $q(x)$ matches $r(x)$ on $(-1,\ 1)\setminus\{0\}$.

Then, by playing with $q(x)$ I realized two interesting things about the function:
$$q(x,a)=\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{a(1-2|x|)}{x^2-|x|}\right)}$$

- The function $q(x,4)$ fits "really good" the function $r(x)$ if I change the definition of $f(x)$ to $$f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}},\quad x>0\\ 0,\quad x\leq 0\end{cases}$$
- The function $q(x,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ "looks like" a perfect smooth transition function with straight-line edges, fulfilling having a derivative with flat tops - but unfortunately it don't fulfill solving a DDE like $y'(x)=k\left(y(2x+1)-y(2x-1)\right)$ for some constant $k$.

You could see them on [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/95jotybd4i):
[image: flat slope]

The lines that fit the slope of $q(x,\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2})$ are: $$L^\pm=\pm \sqrt{3}\ (x\pm 1)-\frac12(\sqrt{3}-1)$$

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146421/discussion-on-question-by-joako-approximation-of-the-fabius-function-with-a-quot); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Comment: @VladimirReshetnikov In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4720147/909869) I explained in detail how I got the approximated function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This question is very interesting since the **Fabius function** is a little **mathematical treasure** and many of its properties can be successfully demonstrated with *Mathematica*. It has a potential of opening new and surprising perspectives on "well-known" theories of mathematics and physics. `FabiusF` can be still improved, nonetheless it already works well.

Let's  define

```
fb = ResourceFunction["FabiusF"];
```

We can evaluate the Fabius function exactly at half integer arguments:

```
Table[fb[x/2], {x, 0, 8}]
```

> ```
>   {0, 1/2, 1, 1/2, 0, -(1/2), -1, -(1/2), 0}
> ```

We could expect that more symbolic properties can be exploited in next versions of this function, especially when it is built-in. We introduce

```
g[x_] /; -1 < x < 1 := (1 + Exp[-(1/RealAbs[x]^(3/4 Sqrt[2 Pi]))])/(
                        1 + Exp[(1 - 2 RealAbs[x])/(x^2 - RealAbs[x])])
g[x_] /; x <= -1 || x >= 1 := 0
```

The above definition of `g` function makes it exactly zero outside the range $(-1,1)$. We have used `RealAbs` instead of `Abs` to evaluate properly derivatives. Now plotting the both functions we find that `g` is a a quite good approximation of `fb`:

```
Plot[{fb[x + 1], g[x]}, {x, -1.02, 1.02}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, 
      PlotStyle -> {{Thickness[0.003]}, {Thick, Dashing[0.01]}}]
```

[image]

Here we find maximal deviations between `fb` and `g` searching for numerical extremal values, symbolic counterparts are not able to evaluate them:

```
Through @ { NMaximize, NMinimize}[{fb[x + 1] - g[x], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

> ```
>   {{0.00336294, {x -> 0.837602}}, {-0.0254221, {x -> 0.632589}}}
> ```

```
Plot[fb[x + 1] - g[x], {x, -1, 1}, PlotStyle -> Thick, AspectRatio -> 1/4] // Quiet
```

[image]

Here one can wonder whether **there might be better approximations** and [Weierstrass Approximation Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html) says **there are better ones even among polynomials** since we are interested in approximations on a compact set. See e.g. [Generating a polynomial that's accurate to within an error of no more than 1/10^5](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/57003/generating-a-polynomial-thats-accurate-to-within-an-error-of-no-more-than-1-10)  and [Get polynomial interpolation formula](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/get-polynomial-interpolation-formula/11799#11799).

Let's compare functions suggested in the commets:

```
u[x_] /; -1 <= x <= 1 := fb[x + 1]
u[x_] /; x < -1 || x > 1 := 0
Plot[{u'[x], 2 (u[2 x + 1] - u[2 x - 1])}, {x, -1, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.008], Dashing[0.004]}]
```

[image]

These functions clearly overlap, however currently we cannot demonstrate symbolically equality of these functions, e.g. `PossibleZeroQ[u'[x] - 2 (u[2 x + 1] - u[2 x - 1]), Assumptions -> -1 < x < 1]` yields `False`.  `FullSimplify` doesn't work either.

Next we re-evaluate first derivatives with appropriate values of `fb` yielding a kind of differential equation for `fb`:

```
Plot[{fb'[x], 2 (fb[2 x] - fb[2 (x - 1)])}, {x, 0, 1}, 
  PlotStyle -> {Dashing[0.008], Dashing[0.004]}]
```

[image]

We have  numerical deviations

```
Plot[fb'[x] - 2 (fb[2 x] - fb[2 (x - 1)]), {x, 0, 1}, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Quality", WorkingPrecision -> 20]
```

[image]

however we can significantly reduce numerical error setting larger `WorkingPrecision`.

Comment: thanks!... could I ask you to check something else? Plase check if numerically/graphically $$u(x)=\begin{cases}\text{FabiusF}(x+1),\quad |x|<1\\ 0,\quad |x|\geq 1\end{cases}$$ satisfies that $$u'(x)=2u(2x+1)-2u(2x-1)$$ at least for $|x|<1$?

Comment: @Joako You are welcome, I'm glad you find it helpful.  I compared numerically  the both functions in my answer, however they don't overlap, changing the arguments they do. Symbolically we cannot prove it if not digging deeper.

Comment: I think it don't match since you use $2fb[2x\pm 1]$ when you need to use $2u[2x\pm 1]$: since $u[x]=fb[x+1]$ you should evaluate in $fb[2x\pm 1+1]$... Don't know If I have explained myself good enough? (since $u'\equiv fb'$ it lead to confusions)

Comment: @Joako Your observation can be regarded as a straightforward consequence of the above calculations.  I'll update my answer a bit later when I find time enough.

Comment: thanks a lot, I just realized that your last review: $$F'[x]=2F[2x]-2F[2(x-1)]$$ is just a translated version $x=y+1$ of$$F'[y+1]=F[(2y+1)+1]-2F[(2y-1)+1]$$ which is equivalent to $$u'[y]=2u[2y+1]-2u[2y-1]$$. Hope you could show the match between $[-1,\ 1]$

Comment: @Artes Very interesting answer! Any idea why exponent `(3/4 Sqrt[2 Pi])`gives an "optimal" approximation? Thanks!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann I wouldn't say that exponent provides an optimal approximation, I believe there might be better ones even among qutients of exponential functions.  Surely there are better polynomial approximations since we have [Weierstass Approximation theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/WeierstrassApproximationTheorem.html).

Comment: I have used one of your plots in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4710367/909869). Please tag me when you test again the $u'(x)=2u(2x+1)-2u(2x-1)$. Thanks again.

Comment: @Joako Yes, we have shown numerically that equation.

Comment: Thank you very much! Amazing answer.

Comment: @Artes Just one more question for the expert: Fabius-function is nowhere analytic(Wikipedia) but Mathematica evaluates powerseries at x==0 and x==1! Where do I make a mistake in thinking?

Comment: @Artes Did you view when doing $$F'(x)=2F(2x)-2F(2(x-1))$$ with $F(x)$ the Fabius function if this formula is also hold on $|x|>1$??

Comment: @UlrichNeumann  I'm not sure what your problem is.  Since $F$ (the Fabius function) is smooth (infinitely differentiable) you can evaluate Tayor series anywhere, however such a series is not convergent to the value of $F$ at given point. Analicity means just that the Taylor series is convergent to the value of the function.  We can define $F$ on the range $(0,1)$ and glue it smoothly with  constant functions at $x=0$ and at $x=1$,  Taylor series has only one non-zero term at these points (constant terms).  Nonetheless constant functions are analytic.  Right?

Comment: @Joako  For any $x<0$ we haxe $F(x)=0$ so it is satisfied trivially. For $x>0$ it should be clear if you evaluate e.g. `Plot[fb[x], {x, 0, 36}, PlotRange -> All]`. I guess you should invest a bit of your resources and buy *Mathematica*  (home edition or student edition or just test the system without paying for it (for a month or two weeks only). I can say it deserves its cost.  It can make many things easier.  Nonetheless in general one should beware of addiction to computer algebra systems.

Comment: @Artes Thank you for your answer. I was wondering, because  Mathematica gives Taylorseries of FabiusF which seem to converge

Comment: @Artes if as you show $$u(x)=\begin{cases} \text{FabiusF}(x+1),\quad |x|<1\\ 0, \quad |x|\geq 0\end{cases}$$ then $u(x)$ fullfils $$u'(x)=2u(2x+1)-2u(2x-1),\quad |x|<1$$, It is obvious then that $z(t)=|\text{FabiusF}(x+1)|$ will fulfill $$z'(x)=2z(2x+1)-2z(2x-1),\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$$ or not?

Comment: @Joako In case you haven't yet seen these papers by Juan Arias de Reyna, I recommend them very much: https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.05442, https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.06487

Answer (score 4):

The Fabius function is approximated well by this piecewise polynomial function:

```
Sum[(-1)^ThueMorse[n] (2 n + 1 - x 2^m)^(m - 1) Sign[2 n + 1 - x 2^m], {n, 0, 2^m - 1}] *
  (-1)^m/(2 * 2^Binomial[m, 2] (m - 1)!)
```

It gives the exact Fabius function in the limit `m -> ∞`. It's derived from the Fourier transform of the Fabius function, which has a representation as an infinite product of `Sinc` functions, by truncating that product after a finite number of terms, and converting it back using the inverse Fourier transform.

You can use this expression with *WolframAlpha* if you substitute an integer for `m`.

[Example](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28%28-1%29%5E5%2F%282%5E%281+%2B+Binomial%5B5%2C+2%5D%29%285-1%29%21%29%29+Sum%5B%28-1%29%5EThueMorse%5Bn%5D+%282n+%2B+1+-+2%5E5+x%29%5E%285+-+1%29+Sign%5B2n+%2B+1+-+2%5E5+x%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+2%5E5+-+1%7D%5D+for+x%3D0+to+1):
[image: WolframAlpha screenshot with the function plot]

---

There is also an exact formula for the values of the Fabius function at dyadic rationals using finite summation, although I don't see how to easily use it to plot the function:

```
FabiusF[m/2^n] == Sum[QBinomial[n, k, 1/2]/(2^(k (k - 1)) (n + k)!)
    Sum[(-1)^ThueMorse[j] (j - m*2^k + 1/2)^(n + k), {j, 0, m*2^k - 1}],
        {k, 0, n}]/(2^(n^2) QPochhammer[1/2, 1/2, n])]
```

---

The Fabius function has a series expansion in Legendre polynomials that is valid for `0 < x < 2`:

```
FabiusF[x] == Sum[LegendreP[2 n, x - 1] 4^(-n) (4 n + 1)
  Sum[(-1)^(n + k) Binomial[2 n, n + k] Binomial[2 n + 2 k, 2 n] (2 k)!
    2^Binomial[2 k + 1, 2] FabiusF[2^(-2 k - 1)], {k, 0, n}], {n, 0, ∞}]
```

You can get a good polynomial approximation by truncating the outer series and replacing `FabiusF[2^(-2 k - 1)]` factors with corresponding rational numbers.

---

A very good simple polynomial approximation on `0 < x < 1/2`:

```
FabiusF[x] ≈ 32 x^5 (7 - 28 x + 40 x^2 - 20 x^3)
```

You can hardly see any difference between their graphs. In a certain sense, this approximation is the best among approximations by interpolating polynomials.

---

In case you need an exact asymptotic of the Fabius function for `x -> 0` in terms of elementary function and the Lambert -function:

```
FabiusF[x] ∝ Exp[(EulerGamma^2/2 - π^2/12 - ProductLog[-1, -x Log[2]] -
  1/2 ProductLog[-1, -x Log[2]]^2 + StieltjesGamma[1])/Log[2]]/(2^(7/12) √π √x)
```

---

See also: [How do I numerically evaluate and plot the Fabius function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/137749/7288)

Comment: thanks.. there is a typo (the last squared bracket). I tried for $m=3$ and $x\equiv x+1$ and indeed plot a function really alike the ones in other answers: look [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=+Sum%5B%28-1%29%5EThueMorse%5Bn%5D+%282+n+%2B+1+-+%28x%2B1%29+2%5E3%29%5E%283+-+1%29+Sign%5B2+n+%2B+1+-+%28x%2B1%29+2%5E3%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+2%5E3+-+1%7D%5D+*+++%28-1%29%5E3%2F%282+*+2%5EBinomial%5B3%2C+2%5D+%283+-+1%29%21%29&lang=es)

Comment: Even though, is really interesting How "good" it have been fitted by a low order polynomial: the function $u(x)=\text{FabiusF}[x+1]$ should be approximated "quite good" by a 1st order polynomial near the points $x = \pm \frac{1}{2}$ since there, its derivatives must become a flat function at a constant value that matches the original function's slope, this because it should be fulfilling $u'(x)=2u(2x+1)-2u(2x-1)$ (if I'm right), in other words, being equal to the scaled/translated versions of itself. (...)

Comment: I fixed the typo, thanks

Comment: (...) This is really mysterious to me since the [Fabius function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabius_function) is known as "an example of an infinitely differentiable function that is nowhere analytic", although, at this point could be approximated exactly by the lower order polynomial.

Comment: also, thinking in how [good looks](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+1%2F%281%2Be%5E%28%281-2%7Cx%7C%29%2F%28x%5E2-%7Cx%7C%29%29%29%2C+1%2F32+%2816+%2B+%281+-+8+x%29+abs%281+-+8+x%29+%2B+%28-3+%2B+8+x%29+abs%283+-+8+x%29+-+5+abs%285+-+8+x%29+%2B+8+x+abs%285+-+8+x%29+%2B+%287+-+8+x%29+abs%287+-+8+x%29%29) to be the approximation I found $q(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^{\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}}}$ and the fact that it should be a line near $x=\pm \frac{1}{2}$ maybe by piecewise  section something interesting could be done (but its out of the scope of what I can do tbh).

Comment: It's a piecewise polynomial, it's stitched from 32 quartic polynomial pieces. You can see it as the result of the iterated refinement process described here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/240687/19661

Comment: Nice, in the answers actually is showed that is fulfilled the Delayed Differential Equation. Probably the term "nowhere analytic" means something different from what I understand (been able of being approximated by a power series).

Comment: I also added a formula for the exact values of the Fabius function at dyadic rationals, but I'm not sure if it's useful for plotting. Theoretically, because the dyadic rationals are dense in ℝ, and the Fabius function is continuous, this formula determines its values at all points.

Comment: I have change a little your first formula using that $x^2\text{sgn(x)}\equiv x|x|$ and it runs faster in Wolfram-Alpha:
Sum[(-1)^ThueMorse[n] (2 n + 1 - x 2^m)^(m - **2**) **Abs** [2 n + 1 - x 2^m], {n, 0, 2^m - 1}] *
  (-1)^m/(2 * 2^Binomial[m, 2] (m - 1)!)

Comment: With $m=3$ now I got [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+1%2F32*%28%281-8x%29*%7C1-8x%7C%2B%288x%2B7%29*%7C8x%2B7%7C-%288x%2B5%29*%7C8x%2B5%7C-%288x%2B3%29*%7C8x%2B3%7C%2B%288x%2B1%29*%7C8x%2B1%7C-%283-8x%29*%7C3-8x%7C-%285-8x%29*%7C5-8x%7C%2B%287-8x%29*%7C7-8x%7C%29%2C+1%2F%281%2Be%5E%28%281-2%7Cx%7C%29%2F%28x%5E2-%7Cx%7C%29%29%29+from+x%3D-1+to+1) (just in case someone want the polynomial without having to type it again in Wolfram-Alpha)

Comment: Finally I asked [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4710367/909869) how it is possible for the Fabius function to be nowhere analytical if it could be fit by a straight line at $x=\frac12$ (this if the [flat top](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flat_function) behavior is true). In case you also got interested.

Comment: Does the polynomial you shared be found as is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/242326/909869), right? It is different from what I am [asking here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4714691/909869)?... I wonder if it is possible to built the same kind of expansion for the function $$q(x,a)=\left(1+\exp\left(\frac{a(1-2|x|)}{x^2-|x|}\right)\right)^{-1}$$ and found some optimal $a^*$ where both approximation become identical... It is possible? Will this imply are the same function?

Comment: Does the area under the first lobe of the fabius function $F(x)$ fulfill $$\int\limits_{-1}^{1} F(x+1)\ dx=1$$?

Comment: @Joako Yes, because of the symmetry. Also, you can verify it using its antiderivative.

Comment: thanks. I found [here](https://oeis.org/A288163) that the function $u(x)=F(x+1)\theta(1-x^2)$ is named as Rvachëv function, and through your formula can be ploted in [Wolfram-Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=plot+%28%28-1%29%5E5%2F%282%5E%281+%2B+Binomial%5B5%2C+2%5D%29%285-1%29%21%29%29+Sum%5B%28-1%29%5EThueMorse%5Bn%5D+%282n+%2B+1+-+2%5E5+%28x%2B1%29%29%5E%285+-+2%29+Abs%5B2n+%2B+1+-+2%5E5+%28x%2B1%29%5D%2C+%7Bn%2C+0%2C+2%5E5+-+1%7D%5D+for+x%3D-1+to+1&lang=es)....

Comment: (...)  I want to use it also in Desmos, but the only piece is stopping me is the term $\text{ThueMorse}[n]$, which if I have understood right what Wikipedia says, it is the pattern how the lobes appears over or below zero in the Fabius function. Now, since the Rvachëv function is only focused in the first lobe, There is any way of avoiding using the $\text{ThueMorse}[n]$ sequence? (since Desmod don't have it natively)

Comment: I have unsuccessfully tried to find something like a function $g(x)$ such as $\frac12 (1+(-1)^{g(x)})$ give the ThueMorse sequence for integer $x\geq 0$ at least until $x=2^5-1$.

Comment: @Joako There is a representation of Thue–Morse via binomial coefficients: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1891648/19661. Also, you can express it via a hypergeometric function: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Thue-MorseSequence.html#:~:text=6.%20A%20closed%2Dform%20expression%20in%20terms%20of%20a%20hypergeometric%20function%2E

Comment: Thanks, I do was able to implement it in [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/wriue5o51i), but it struggles a bit with it.

Comment: Later I realized that the function $$g(x) = \begin{cases} 1,\quad x=0, \\ 0, \quad x=-1 \vee x=1, \\
\frac{1}{1+\exp\left(\frac{1-2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)}, \ \text{otherwise} \end{cases} $$ could be also **an example of a discontinuous function with continuous derivative**. It have many interesting properties I was unaware of (specialy since I found it accidentally trying to match the [Rvachëv function](https://oeis.org/A288163) functional equation DDE).

Answer (score 3):

Extended comment:

Optimal exponent `a=?` for the approximation

[image]

If we take the general ansatz `FabiusF[x+1]~(1 + Exp[-1/x^(a Sqrt[2 Pi])])/(1 + Exp[(1 - 2 x)/(x^2 - x)]), 0<x<1, a>0` the approximation error depends on `a`:

```
err[a_?NumericQ] :=NIntegrate[(ResourceFunction["FabiusF"][x + 1] - (1 + Exp[-1/x^(a Sqrt[2 Pi])])/(1 + Exp[(1 - 2 x)/(x^2 - x)]))^2, {x, 0, 1}] 

pic = LogPlot[err[a], {a, 0, 2.5}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "err[a]"} ](* takes some time...*)
```

[image]

In the plot we see a minimum at `a~1.64` !

```
pi = Cases[pic, Line[p_] :> p, -1][[1]] ;
opta = Select[pi, Min[pi] == #[[2]] &][[1]] (*{1.64427, -11.8112}*)
```

Comparing for different a-values

```
Plot[Evaluate[
Map[ResourceFunction["FabiusF"][x + 1] - (1 + Exp[-1/x^(# Sqrt[2 Pi])])/(1 + Exp[(1 - 2 x)/(x^2 - x)]) &, { 3/4, opta[[1]], GoldenRatio}]], {x, 0, 1},PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}, Gray}, 
PlotLegends ->LineLegend[{ 3/4, 1.64427, GoldenRatio // N}, LegendLabel -> "parameter a:"],PlotRange->All]
```

[image]

it looks like parameter value `a=1.64427  ~GoldenRatio`  gives a better approximation for the fabius-function!

**addendum**

comparison of the derivatives of the approximation error:

```
Plot[Evaluate[
  Map[Derivative[1, 0][ 
      Function[{x, a}, 
       ResourceFunction["FabiusF"][x + 1] - (
        1 + Exp[-1/x^(# Sqrt[2 Pi])])/(
        1 + Exp[(1 - 2 x)/(x^2 - x)])]][u, a] &, { 3/4, opta[[1]], 
    GoldenRatio}]], {u, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, {Red, Dashed}, Gray}, 
 PlotLegends -> 
  LineLegend[{ 3/4, 1.64427, GoldenRatio // N}, 
   LegendLabel -> "parameter a:"], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Hope it helps!

Comment: The problem with your value is that we were "optimizing" different things: my objective where to have "flat" lobes in the derivative, which happen near the value $1.87$, if you change the exponent with something bigger than $2.5$ its become rounded, as you could see [here in Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/vrny5s9rc2?lang=es), at your value the derivative already looks rounded as the derivative $g'(x)$ of $g(x)=\left(1+\exp\left(\frac{1+2|x|}{x^2-|x|}\right)\right)$ which is different of the Fabius function $\text{FabiusF}[x+1]$ that do have flat lobes in its derivatives

Comment: My idea was founding at least a function that was such as its derivatives where proportional to displaced versions of itself $u'(x)=k\left(u(2x+1)-u(2x-1)\right)$ for some $k>0$, and since the original functions have a flat top, I was trying to find also a function which derivatives have also flat top lobes

Comment: @Joako My approximation gives smaller slopes too, I think! Or did I misunderstand "flat lobes in the derivative"?

Comment: I graphed [here in desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/do6nd4ym3y) the derivatives of the original function and what I understood is your version: you could see that the last one don't have flat lobes

Comment: @Joako Ok thanks for the explanation. I modified my answer end added plot of derivatives of the approximation error

Comment: I believe I found an example of a funcrtion with perfectly flat top derivative: I just added to the question.

Comment: @Joako Very interesting , thanks!

Comment: Do you believe is possible to find an optimal $a^*$ for fitting the Fabius function $u(x)=\text{FabiusF}[x+1]$ with $$q(x,a)=\left(1+\exp\left(\frac{a(1-2|x|)}{x^2-|x|}\right)\right)^{-1}?$$

Comment: @Joako The quadratic error `err[a_?NumericQ] := 
 NIntegrate[(ResourceFunction["FabiusF"][x + 1] - 1 /(
     1 + Exp[a (1 - 2 x)/(x^2 - x)]))^2 , {x, 0, 1}]` shows (`LogPlot[err[a], {a, 0, 2}, AxesLabel -> {"a", "err[a]"} ] `)a minimum for `a==1`. Not really surprising...

Comment: @Joako `NMinimize[{Log[err2[a]], 0 < a < 2}, a, Method -> "NelderMead"]` evaluates `{-11.6135, {a -> 0.997659}}`

Comment: I were expecting something different, a bit stretched on the edges but no as so the last example I uploaded (so between $a=1$ and $a=0.85$)

Comment: Your "expectation" depends on the `err[...]`function, which should be modified

Comment: By playing with Desmos I think that $a*$ such it has straight-line edges is $a=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$.. I fixed it now on the last upload

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, I didn't take limits, I just used `Table` in MMA to plug numbers in and only did this as a very quick very simple attempt to get you something.

Please, be very cautious with this and check all the details of this before you even think of beginning to trust this. I didn't study the links that others supplied to explore the depths of evaluating the Fabius function. I just did the three lines of MMA code to let you peek at the results and hoped that would be enough to help you. If you study the depths of the steps of precise evaluation of your approximation then you may be able to understand why MMA is concerned about the value of this at 0.

`Plot` will sometimes have problems just plugging in numbers.

In the next step I used `/.x->0` to just plug in zero.

In the final step I used `Limit` to check that result at zero.

If you find any mistakes in what I did then I am sorry and if you try to simply explain how I need to fix those then I will try to do what I can. Hope this helps you get what you need done.

[image]

Comment: thanks you very much for taking the time to answer. I don't know why your functions don't match the full plot, so I recomend you to check the answer by @Artes where the graphs do match.