# Finding the equation of curve?

Tags: numerics

I am not sure which level cure it will be, what I have is domain and range for it which are as follows.

```
f(0) = 0
f(1) = 1
f(2) = 1
f(3) = 3
f(4) = 5
f(5) = 8
f(6) = 13
f(7) = 21
f(8) = 34
f(9) = 55
f(10) = 89
```

It's programmaticly tough to find out the values beyond `f(10)` hence is there any way i can figure it out mathematically.

As a wild guess I think is will repeat after some interval so must be a curve but any lead is appreciated !

Comment: This post answers your problem; [Get polynomial interpolation formula](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/get-polynomial-interpolation-formula/11799#11799)

Comment: Is it correct that you are skipping `f(8)`?

Comment: Yes I skipped f(5) although it would be there

Comment: This looks like the Fibonacci sequence, but there should have been a 2 between 1 and 3 (and 8 is omitted).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the data in a *Mathematica* list:

```
data = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {3, 3}, {4, 5}, {6, 13}, {7, 21}, {8, 34}, {9, 55}, {10, 89}}
```

Plot it:

```
ListPlot[data]
```

[image]

Looks exponential. Try a fit:

```
fit = NonlinearModelFit[data, a Exp[b x] + c, {a, b, c}, x]
```

We get a `FittedModel` object in return. The fit is very good:

```
fit["RSquared"]
```

> 0.999952

The best fitting model is

```
fit["BestFit"]
```

> `-0.490631 + 0.774275 E^(0.474907 x)`

Comment: I skipped some inputs, although i got your answer, just wanted to notify that the question was changed, Thanks !

Comment: I do not understand, can you give links to how you did it ? and how do i get the equation of line is it `-1.74487 + 1.33712 E^(0.468692 x)` ?

Comment: Yes, that is the function that best fits the points. The commands I've written in my answer is the way I did it: the code should be clear enough, if you read the documentation for `NonlinearModelFit`. You do realize this is the SE for the software _Mathematica_ by Wolfram, right...? You don't mention it in your OP.

Comment: Then you have posted on the wrong StackExchange site.

Comment: Can you please correct your answer according to the corrected inputs, so that I can accept the answer as correct ?

Comment: Done :) Notice that the best fit function has changed a little now, of course

Comment: Of course, I tried it myself, thanks for introducing me to Mathematica !!