# Finding a polynomial fit to a set of data

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I am trying to find a polynomial to fit the data listed as

```
data = {{0,6.67},{6,17.33},{10,42.67},{13,37.33},{17,30.10},{20,29.31},{28,28.74}}
```

I set this string equal to data and use the routine

```
LinearModelFit[data,{x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6},x]
```

The answer I get is

```
Fitted Model[6.67-42.6435x +16.1427x^2 -<<19>>x^3 +<<20>>x^4 -0.00367168x^5 +0.0000409458x^6.
```

I don't understand why i am not getting any factors for the x^3 x^4 terms. Is there some way I can rectify this situation?

Comment: You are getting all the terms. Use `Normal` to see the model.

Comment: Perhaps `InterpolatingPolynomial` might help you, see e.g. [Get polynomial interpolation formula](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/11794/get-polynomial-interpolation-formula/11799#11799).

Comment: Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5, x^6}, x] gives quite a good fit.  If you want to exclude3 the x^3 and x^4 terms, simply exclude them from the fit.  Such as this: Fit[data, {1, x, x^2, x^5, x^6}, x].  The result isn't nearly as good a fit to the original.

Answer (score 1):

As per @MelaGo...

```
Normal@LinearModelFit[data,{x,x^2,x^3,x^4,x^5,x^6},x]
```

> 6.67 - 42.6435 x + 16.1427 x^2 - 2.09464 x^3 + 0.126902 x^4 - 
>    0.00367168 x^5 + 0.0000409458 x^6