# Gram-Schmidt process with Hermite functions on [-1, 1]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

Denote by $h_n$ the $n$-th Hermite function.
$$
h_n(x) = \frac{(-1)^n }{\sqrt{2^n n! \sqrt{\pi}}} \mathrm{e}^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \frac{\mathrm{d}^n}{\mathrm{d} x^n} \mathrm{e}^{-x^2} 
$$

I am trying to find the 40th, 41st and 42nd terms in Gram-Schmidt process with Hermite functions $h_n$  on $[-1, 1]$.

I've  used the usual procedure for [Gram-Schmidt process](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process), but I've been able to calulate only the first 6 terms and then my computer got stuck.

Is there some way to calculate them?

Comment: Is this question related to Mathematica (TM)? Can you post your Mathematica code?

Comment: Have you seen this? http://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/HermiteHGeneral/02/

Comment: Related (duplicate?): http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/22040/5

Comment: @ bill s: as I understand, its Hermit polynomial-not function...

Comment: @Mack what is your weight function on the interval to get normalized Hermite polynomials?

Comment: Maybe you could show us how you used Mathematica to do the first 6 terms?

Comment: To the closers: I don't see any reason to close this as off topic. Mathematica has a function to deal with problems like this(`Orthogonalize`), so to me it looks like a fine Mathematica topic.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Mma has functions to deal with many problems. But the OP didn't answer the question in the first comment, and there is no code either.

Comment: @belisarius That's not nice, but is that sufficient reason to close? Id say the question is answerable quite easily with the information that was provided..

Comment: Related (possible duplicate?) of [Why does Expand not work within a function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/why-does-expand-not-work-within-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the Wikipedia article you referred, here is a code

```
u[1] = HermiteH[1, x];
Do[
  u[n] = HermiteH[n, x] - Sum[Integrate[HermiteH[n, x] u[i], 
  {x, -1.0, 1.0}], {i, 1,n-1}], {n, 2, 45}
];
```