# Reuse symbolic polynomial

Tags: memoization

Suppose I have a function that returns a polynomial in `x`,

```
GetPoly[params_,x_]:=GetPoly[params,x]...
```

but it is quite slow, so I memoize this. 
However, doing `GetPoly[params,2y]` or similar do not utilize the memoized data, it does the same computation now with `2y`.

What is the best way to reuse the existing computation?

The solution I can cook up is to use an auxiliary function that computes the polynomial symbolically, and then substitute with the actual symbol/value:

```
GetPoly[params_,x_]:=AuxPoly[params,y]/.{y->x};
AuxPoly[params_,x_]:=AuxPoly[params,x]...
```

Is this the best solution to my problem? 
What is the convention to do this in a package?

Comment: Does the calculation of the polynomial change at all based on `x`, or only the parameters?  That is, is there ever a case where to get from `GetPloy[params1, x1]` to `GetPloy[params1, x2]` is more complicated than simply substituting `x2` for `x1`?

Comment: It is not clear how your code looks like so maybe this question dealing with a memoization technique for certain polynomials: [Why does Expand not work within a function?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/4652/why-does-expand-not-work-within-a-function) and answers providing  correct implementations will be helpful.

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53)?

Comment: @JasonB: Simply substituting. That's exactly what happens. But different params give different polynomials.

Comment: @PerAlexandersson Then I would definitely do it the way you have at the end of the post.

Comment: @JasonB: Ok, I'll go for that then. Was thinking there was a cleaner way to do it , but I guess not.