# Tabulating Numeric Approximation

Tags: numerics

I was wondering how to approximate or tabulate values for this numeric approximation: It is the  following: The confusing part is how to implement the subscripts in mathematica.

$y_{i+1} = (t_i - y_i)h + y_i$

I want to do something of the following for this numeric solution.

```
x[t_] = t/(1 + t^4);
data = N[Table[{t, x[t]}, {t, -5, 5}], 2];
tableofcontents = Prepend[data, {"t", "x(t)"}];
Text@Grid[tableofcontents, Alignment -> Right, Dividers -> {Center, {False, True}}, 
  Spacings -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Look at `RecurrenceTable[]`. What are you *actually* trying to do, and what results are you expecting?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mathematica+recurrence or http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-can-i-implement-dynamic-programming-for-a-function-with-more-than-one-argume

Comment: what is the definition of $h$ and $t_i$?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries: $h=1/n$, is the step size. $t_i$, is the time steps.

Comment: @J.M.: Approximate a solution to the equation in order to compare with the tabulated true solution values for the same time steps.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you look at `RecurrenceTable` as J. M. suggested. However to give you an idea of how you would implement subscripts (by which I think you mean recursion) in a "normal" way, here's a simple example using the Fibonacci sequence:

```
f[0] = 1;
f[1] = 1;
f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2];
```

For performance you would also "memoize", which just means that you store every result so that you don't have to recalculate it later:

```
f[0] = 1;
f[1] = 1;
f[n_] := (
   f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2]
);
```

Notice that the `f[n] =` within the function is not `f[n_] :=`, because we aren't matching to a generic pattern and we don't need to recalculate the expression every time it's used. We're telling *Mathematica* that `f` applied to the specific value that `n` has at that time is whatever it calculates on the right-hand side at that time, so the usage there is like array indexing. It's the same as was done in the first two lines specifying `f[0]` and `f[1]`.

And for the sake of completeness, here's the `RecurrenceTable` version of the Fibonacci sequence that I pulled straight out of the documentation:

```
RecurrenceTable[{a[n] == a[n - 1] + a[n - 2], a[1] == 1, a[2] == 1}, a, {n, 10}]
```