# Why does Mathematica use [[ ]] notation for array indexing?

Tags: syntax, language-design

I am confused by why *Mathematica* uses `[[3]]` to get the 3rd element, or `[[i,j]` to get the i,j-th element of a 2D array.

This seems counter-intuitive. Is this main reason for this to separate array-indexing from function calls?

i.e. where I see:

```
f[3, 4] <-- this is currently function call
f[[3, 4]] <-- f is a 2D array, and we're accessing 3,4-th element
```

**Question**:

Given that Mathematica knows the type of the arguments, can't it infer:

- if we're dealing with a function, apply arguments
- if the object is an array, index it?

  Thus, why do we need separate `[[ ]]` notation for array indexing?

Comment: most programs are written to also be read by other _humans_, in which case the distinction between `[[ ]]` and `[ ]` is helpful.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

In addition to Brett's counter-example, it might be helpful to view this from *Mathematica*'s philosophy, which is "everything is an expression". In this framework, you're not really indexing a 1D/2D array, but you're *extracting* a `Part` from an *expression*.

Indeed, you can use the `⟦ ⟧` notation on any expression, not just lists/matrices. For example:

```
Sin[x + y][[1]]
(* x + y *)

Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}][[1, 1]]
(* RGBColor[1, 0, 0] *)
```

The output of `Part` on any expression can be viewed as the argument of *some* function in the `FullForm` of the expression. For example, breaking down the second example above:

```
Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}][[1]]
(* {RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Disk[{0, 0}]} <-- argument of Graphics[] *) 

Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}][[1, 1]]
(* RGBColor[1, 0, 0] <-- argument of List[] *)

Graphics[{Red, Disk[]}][[1, 2, 1]]
(* {0, 0} <-- argument of Disk[] *)
```

The 0th part is the `Head` of the entire expression. Since none of the above constitute as being a function call, it makes sense to use a different notation to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 18):

No.

For example, functions do not have to be atomic.  It can be possible to extract parts from them (although it's generally not recommended.)

```
In[1]:= if=Interpolation[Range[10]^2]

Out[1]= InterpolatingFunction[{{1,10}},<>]

In[2]:= if[3]

Out[2]= 9

In[3]:= if[[3]]

Out[3]= {{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}}
```

Answer (score 9):

Let me give two examples illustrating the conceptual difference between `Part` and `[]`.

Here's an example showing how parts of every expression, even graphics expressions, can be accessed using `Part`:

```
g = Graphics[Circle[]];
g
g // FullForm
```

so `g` is, in fact, `Graphics[Circle[List[0, 0]]]`, even though Mathematica displays it in the front-end as

[image: Mathematica graphics]

So you can extract its parts directly: `g[[1, 1, 2]]` evaluates to `0`, for example.

So `Part` is a way of accessing specific parts on an expression tree.

On the other hand, you can think of `f[2]` as analogous to a hashtable. Thus,

```
Do[f[i] = RandomReal[], {i, 3}]
DownValues[f]
(*
{HoldPattern[f[1]] :> 0.201718, 
 HoldPattern[f[2]] :> 0.287401, 
 HoldPattern[f[3]] :> 0.531829}
*)
```

and eg `f[2]` evaluates to `0.287401`. Defining this kind of thing with patterns, like `f[x_]:=x^2` is no different: you are merely matching a more general pattern than you are with eg `f[3]`. You could have arbitrary expressions inside the brackets, and this is often used to implement [memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2639/what-is-x-x-trickery), although it needs some work for [more complicated situations](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53/how-can-i-implement-dynamic-programming-for-a-function-with-more-than-one-argume).

So actually `f[[3]]` and `f[3]` are conceptually completely different operations.