# Automatic Handling of bracket vs double-bracket errors

Tags: code-request, debugging

In the thick of programming, I often make bracket/double-bracket errors, such as

```
Tr[[matrix]] instead of Tr[matrix]
```

or

```
list[1] instead of list[[1]].
```

Unfortunately, in the former the error message

```
Part::pspec: Part specification A is neither an integer nor a list of integers.
```

doesn't uniquely specify and localize the problem in a long program, and in the latter no error message is generated at all.  (If any Wolfram employees are reading this, please consider generating a more informative error message for `Print[["hello"]]` that flags that `Print` was bracketed as a list instead of a function.)

I couldn't think of a reason why Mathematica necessarily needs different kinds of brackets for functions and lists.  The bracket/double-bracket convention lets you distinguish functions from lists by context, but it decreases readability of complicated expressions and makes me prone to coding mistakes. *Note added:* Albert Retey commented that if `f` is defined as a pure function via `f=Function[x,x^2]` (rather than as `f[x_]=x^2`) then `f[1]` and `f[[1]]` are simultaneously defined and nonequal unless `x=1`.  This gave the example I hadn't thought possible and (to make matters worse) provided a bracket/double bracket hazard which won't generate even a cryptic error message.

In the case of functions, I partially solved the problem by manually applying the following function declaration to all native functions (except `Function[ ]` itself) and to user-defined non-pure functions:

```
Attributes[DeclareFunction] = {HoldAll};
DeclareFunction::HeadInvalid = "The Argument `1` of DeclareFunction 
    must have a head other than Function.";
DeclareFunction[f_] := 
    If[Head[f] === Function, 
        Message[DeclareFunction::HeadInvalid, f], 
        Block[{prot}, 
            prot = MemberQ[Attributes[f], Protected];
            Unprotect[f]; 
            f::FunctionAsList = "Changed `1`[[ ]] to `1`[ ]";
            f[[x__]] ^:= (Message[f::FunctionAsList, f]; f[x]);
            If[prot, Protect[f]]]]
```

After `DeclareFunction` is applied to a function `f`, the offending double-brackets are automatically interpreted as single-brackets and a warning message is given, pointing out the function with the offending double-bracket: After

```
DeclareFunction[Print]
```

the command

```
Print[["Hello"]]
```

yields

```
Print::FunctionAsList: Changed Print[[ ]] to Print[ ] >>
Hello
```

However,

1. Is there a way to write an analogous `DeclareList` command?  Once `DeclareList[list]` is invoked, `list[ ]` should be automatically converted to `list[[ ]]` with a warning message given.
2. It would also be nice to find an unobtrusive way to invoke `DeclareFunction` automatically any time a new function is defined using the usual `f[x_]:=` method.  A complication is that if I modify the function `SetDelayed[ ]` then I run into issues of the modification recursing on itself instantly as it is made.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may find this useful: type ESC [[ ESC to get a special double-bracket character which is (in my opinion) much more readable. I always use this character. Since I find ESC [[ ESC too time consuming to type, I set up Ctrl-[ as a keyboard shortcut to type it more easily.

Comment: "I couldn't think of a reason why Mathematica necessarily needs different kinds of brackets for functions and lists." Have you never used indexed variables; i.e., `a[1]`, `a[2]`, ....? Both `a[1] = 42` and `a[[1]] = 42` are valid and useful assignment expressions that mean very different things, and are an example of the why Mathematica has single and double bracket notation.

Comment: Note that `someList[[i]]` is just syntactic sugar for `Part[someList, i]`

Comment: I tried

a={b,c,d}; a[[1]]=1; a[1]=1

and got an error message.  I infer that mathematica won't let me simultaneously use the variable a as a list and a function, so that a must either have single brackets (as a function) or double brackets (as a list) but can't have both.

Am I missing something?

Comment: "I infer that *Mathematica* won't let me simultaneously use the variable a as a list and a function" - you infer right. If `a` is an indexed variable or a function, you use `[]`. Also, it is entirely possible to use `Part[]` on "non-atomic heads" (see e.g. [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/8122)), and it is possible to have a list as a head, e.g. `Through[{Sin, Cos}[30 °]]`.

Comment: @J.M. Yes, but [{Sin, Cos}[30 °]] doesn't give {Sin[30],Cos[30]}, without some post-processing.  I guess upshot of your point is that you wouldn't want to automatically run the hypothetical DeclareList command on every list, just deliberately on some of them.

Comment: here is an example where `[]` vs. `[[]]` makes a difference: `f = Function[x, x^2]`. Try `f[1]` vs. `f[[1]]`, both are valid operations but in this case return different results

Comment: @Albert Retey  Yes, that's a good example.

Comment: @Albert Retey  That is an interesting subtlety that you point out:  f=Function[x,x^2] and f[x_]=x^2 are not at all the same thing.

PS. I don't know how you guys are getting the grey boxes.  I don't have enough reputation to experiment.

Comment: (By that I mean that my reputation points don't allow me to edit comments to play around until the boxes work, nor will it let me delete them.)

Comment: Use backticks to delimit code; e.g. `\`Sin[x]\`​` gives `Sin[x]`.

Comment: "Unfortunately, in the former the error message `Part::pspec` doesn't uniquely specify and localize the problem in a long program". You can make use of the debugger, check [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119307/1871) for more information.

Comment: @xzczd I have previously been completely unable to get the debugger to work, but I just installed Wolfram workbench.  (Hopefully that will be easier.)

Comment: You may also want to read [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/119916/1871).

Comment: @xzczd I found that page yesterday, and the comments there are what told me to go install workbench.

Comment: I really recommend you to have a look at my answer there. Notice it's written this year, while most of the comments are posted 3 years ago. (The debugger of Mathematica has been underestimated for a long time. )

Comment: @xzczd Will do.  I take it you don't recommend using workbench?

Comment: I dare not say that, because I never used workbench. I just want to point out  the debugger of _Mathematica_ is enough to locate the source of `Part::pspec` warning.

Answer (score 3):

*Just noticed that @Szabolcs mentions this in the first OP comment.*

You can better distinguish between [`Part`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Part.html) and other bracket syntax by using the shorthand [`LeftDoubleBracket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/LeftDoubleBracket.html), <kbd>Esc</kbd> [[ <kbd>Esc</kbd> , and shorthand [`RightDoubleBracket`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/character/RightDoubleBracket.html),  <kbd>Esc</kbd> ]] <kbd>Esc</kbd> .

Using the OP examples.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now it is clear when `Part` is being called and when it is not.  I always use `LeftDoubleBracket` and `RightDoubleBracket` to avoid the confusion you are experiencing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: @user9490 No, it would not be useful.  A simple example, `N[Max[list]]`. You would not want `]]` converted in countless cases. For consistency of the in front end you explicitly use the shorthand for both double brackets.