# How to generate a recurrent sequence

Tags: recursion

How to generate this type of sequence?
$$ f(n, x) = x f'(n-1, x) \hspace{2 mm}, f(0, x) = e^x$$
How do I evaluate it for numerical values for $x = 1$ or any number?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something like :

```
NestList[x D[#, x] &, Exp[x], 3]

(* {E^x, E^x x, x (E^x + E^x x), x (E^x + E^x x + x (2 E^x + E^x x))} *)

NestList[x D[#, x] &, Exp[x], 3] /. x-> 1

(* {E, E, 2 E, 5 E} *)
```

Comment: works ... and how do i evaluate it for x=1?

Comment: You can define a function as @J.M. did or you can take the output and substitute your value for x : `NestList[x D[#, x] &, Exp[x], 3] /. x-> 1`

Answer (score 5):

Leonid's method [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60) can be easily adapted to your example:

```
experimentX[0, x_] := E^x;
experimentX[n_Integer, x_] := 
  Module[{xl}, 
   Set @@ Hold[experimentX[n, xl_], xl D[experimentX[n - 1, xl], xl]];
   experimentX[n, x]];
```

Comment: Do your gravatars change with Firefox releases? I likes it...

Comment: No, @Yves; I molt on a weekly basis. :)

Answer (score 4):

This pair of definitions will do what you want:

```
Clear[f];
f[n_, x_] /; IntegerQ[n] && n >= 1 := f[n, x] = x D[f[n - 1, x], x] // Simplify;
f[0, x_] = E^x;
```

It uses ["memoisation"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2639/) to save recomputing earlier results.

Comment: This definition **doesn't work** if the second argument is a number, and OP wanted to be able to evaluate the function...

Comment: My apologies. If you insert f[n_, z_?NumericQ] := f[n, x] /. x -> z after the Clear[f] I think it fixes the problem. But this is a bit of a hack because it assumes  that you want to use "x" as the dummy variable.