# Derivative operator not working for the function defined as F[0, x_] = Sin[x]

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to define a sequence of functions
$$
F_0(x), F_1(x), \dots
$$
where each function $F_{k+1}(x)$ is defined using $F_k'(x)$. For simplicity let's assume that
$$
F_{k+1}(x) = F_k'(x).
$$

I'm using the following (not working) *Mathematica* code:

```
F[0, x_] = Sin[x]
F[kp1_, x_] := F[kp1_, x_] = With[{k = kp1 - 1},
  Derivative[0, 1][F][k, x]
]
F[1, s^2]
```

The code gives `$RecursionLimit::reclim` due to

```
Derivative[0, 1][F][0, x]
```

is not evaluating and I have no idea how to fix that.

Actually I can introduce  dummy variable and use `D` instead of `Derivative`

```
F[0, x_] = Sin[x]
F[kp1_, x_] := F[kp1_, x_] = With[{k = kp1 - 1},
  D[F[k, y], y] /. y -> x
]
F[1, s^2]
```

This code works flawlessly, but in my actual problem there's a lot of variables and introducing new variables will make a huge mess, so I would like to stick with `Derivative` operator.

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/8903)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second method can be done with an "anonymous" substitute for `y`, namely, [`Slot[1]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html):

```
ClearAll[F];
F[0, x_] = Sin[x];
F[kp1_, x_] := F[kp1, x] = With[{k = kp1 - 1}, Evaluate[D[F[k, #], #]] &@x]

F[1, s^2]
(*  Cos[s^2]  *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this --- I suppose that the initial function is Sin[x]

```
F[x_][0] := Sin[x]
F[x_][n_] := F[x][n] = D[F[x][n - 1], x]
```

Comment: What if x is not a symbol?

Comment: Give an exemple

Comment: Example `F[s^2][1]`

Comment: I dont understand: should one make the integration on s ? If it is the case, the formula works in the same way F[s_][0] := Sin[s^2]
F[s_][n_] := F[s^2][n] = D[F[s^2][n - 1], s]

Comment: Of cvourse I should have written derivation in place of integration