# Fast Spherical Harmonics radiative transfer

Tags: performance-tuning, numerics, special-functions, code-review

This is a rather specific question and I apologize for spamming you with some lengthy code. But it could be interesting for some reader and maybe you can help out, so please bear with me.

I am using the [Spherical Harmonics Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_harmonics) to solve a radiative transfer problem in spherical symmetry, namely the [penetration of diffuse UV radiation into interstellar clouds](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1980ApJ...236..598F). It uses an expansion in [Legendre polynomials](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials) to approximate the depth and angular dependence of the problem.

I have a working solution and I am interested in a some additional input:

1. Is there a more elegant/simpler way to set up solutions for the intensity for varying values of $\omega$ (scattering albedo) and g (mean scattering angle $\langle \cos(\theta)\rangle$)
2. My solution is monochromatic and still relatively slow. For real applications one needs to perform the same calculations on a wavelength grid numerous times. How to speed up the solution? Wouldn't it be neat if *Mathematica* could do the radiative transfer efficiently?
3. For higher approximation order, solving the Eigenvalue problem and getting the list of $A_m$ from the boundary conditions becomes extremely slow. Any ideas on how to improve?

Here is what I got so far. First some definitions:

```
(* definition of the modified spherical Bessel function of the first kind *)
SphericalBesselI[0, 0] := SphericalBesselI[0, 0] = 1;
SphericalBesselI[l_, z_] := Sqrt[π/(2 z)] BesselI[l + 1/2, z];
(* expansion coefficients for the Henyey-Greenstein phase function *)
σ[l_][g_] := g^l
(* diagonal matrix elements *)
h[l_][g_, ω_] := h[l][g, ω] = (2 l + 1) (1 - ω σ[l][g]);
(* low-order determinants *)
F[0][g_, ω_][k_] := F[0][g, ω][k] = -h[0][g, ω];
F[1][g_, ω_][k_] := F[1][g, ω][k] = h[0][g, ω] h[1][g, ω] - k^2;
F[l_][g_, ω_][k_] := F[l][g, ω][k] = -h[l][g, ω] F[l - 1][g, ω][k] -
  l^2 k^2 F[l - 2][g, ω][k];
(* helper function to access the i-th Eigenvalue k *)
kEV::mmatch = "Inconsistent list of Eigenvalues.";
kEV[list_List][m_Integer] := Module[{pos, neg},
   pos = Select[Sort@list, Positive];
   neg = Select[Sort@list, Negative];
   If[(Length[pos] == Length[neg]) && m <= Length[pos],
     If[Positive[m], pos[[m]], neg[[m]]],
     Message[kEV::mmatch]; $Failed]];
(* calculate the Eigenvalues *)
calculateEigenvalues[L_][g_, ω_] := 
   NSolve[F[L][g, ω][k] == 0, k][[All, 1, 2]];
R[0, m_][g_, ω_][k_] := R[0, m][g, ω][k] = 1;
R[1, m_][g_, ω_][k_] := R[1, m][g, ω][k] = (1 - ω)/k[m];
R[l_Integer, m_Integer][g_, ω_][k_] /; m < 0 := R[l, m][g, ω][k] = (-1)^l R[l, -m][g, ω][k]
R[l_Integer, m_][g_, ω_][k_] :=  R[l, m][g, ω][k] = 
     1/(l k[m]) (h[l - 1][g, ω] R[l - 1, m][g, ω][
      k] - (l - 1) k[m] R[l - 2, m][g, ω][k]);
(* Mark's boundary condition *)
getAngles[M_Integer] := 
 Sort@Select[
 List @@ (NRoots[LegendreP[2 M, x] == 0, x] /. Equal[_, x_] :> x), 
 Negative] 
B[i_Integer, m_Integer][g_?NumberQ, ω_?NumberQ][Lmax_, 
   taumax_?NumberQ, k_, angles_] := 
   Sum[(2 l + 1) R[l, m][g, ω][k] LegendreP[l, 
   angles[[i]]] SphericalBesselI[l, k[m] taumax], {l, 0, Lmax}];
```

Now the procedure to set up function to calculate the mean intensity (averaged over the full solid angle) as function of the optical depth $\tau$ and the specific intensity as function of optical depth $\tau$ and angle $\mu=\cos(\theta)$.

```
createSphericalHarmonics[g_, ω_, I0_, tauMax_, L_?OddQ] := 
 Module[
  {M = (L + 1)/2, angles, eigenvalues, kEigenValues, AList},
  (* angles for the boundary conditions from Mark's condition *)
  angles = -SetPrecision[getAngles[M], Infinity];
  (* calculate Eigenvalues from the recurrence relations F*)
  eigenvalues = 
    SetPrecision[calculateEigenvalues[L][g, ω], Infinity];
  (* calculate the A_k from the boundary conditions, i.e. 
     that the incoming intensity at the edge of the sphere and at
     angle_i equals I_ 0*)
  (* assuming isotropic illumination gives ConstantArray[I0, Mmax]. 
     Alternatively we could define an I_ 0[mu] as declination dependent I_ 0*)
  AList = LinearSolve[
     N[SetPrecision[
        Table[B[i, m][g, ω][L, tauMax, kEV[eigenvalues], angles], 
              {i, 1, M}, {m, 1, M}]
      , Infinity], 30], 
     N[SetPrecision[ConstantArray[I0, M], Infinity], 30]];

 (* the N[#, 30] should prevent the LinearSolve::luc error but it doesn't *)
 (* output are two InterpolationFunctions: {mean intensity as function of tau, intensity as function of angle and optical depth tau} *)
 {
  Function[tau, 
   Sum[AList[[m]] R[0, m][g, ω][
   kEV[eigenvalues]] SphericalBesselI[
   0, (tauMax - tau) kEV[eigenvalues][m]], {m, 1, M}]],
  Function[{tau, mu},
   Sum[(2 l + 1) LegendreP[l, mu] Sum[
   AList[[m]] R[l, m][g, ω][
     kEV[eigenvalues]] SphericalBesselI[
     l, (tauMax - tau) kEV[eigenvalues][m]], {m, 1, M}], {l, 0, L}]]
  }
 ]
```

To demonstrate the solution, let's assume $g=0.5$, albedo $\omega=0.6$, approximation order of the Legendre polynomials $L=19$ and incoming intensity $I_0=1$, and optical depth to cloud center $\tau_c=10$.

```
{meanIntensity, intensity} = createSphericalHarmonics[0.5, 0.6, 1., 10, 19];

PolarPlot[{1, intensity[0, Cos[mu]], intensity[1, Cos[mu]]}, {mu, 0, π/2}, 
     Epilog -> {Dashed, (Line[{{0, 0}, {Cos[ArcCos @ #], 
     Sin[ArcCos @ #]}}] & /@ (-getAngles[10]))}]
```

[image: polar plot of intensity]

The wavy curve is the approximated intensity as function of angle $\mu$ at the surface of the cloud, the dashed lines show the angles that were used to specify the boundary conditions. The olive curve shows the angular dependence of the intensity at $\tau=1$.

The angular averaged, mean intensity:

```
Plot[Log10@(meanIntensity[tau]/meanIntensity[0]), {tau, 0, 10}, 
     PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All}]
```

[image: plot of angular mean intensity]

I am pretty sure there are plenty of bugs still in the code, but they are not the point of this post, but rather the performance and coding style.

Comment: @J.M. thanks for the edits :)

Comment: Heh, no worries. Answering this will require a fair amount of thought; I'll need to mull over this...

Comment: As a starting point: ``getAngles[M_Integer] := 2 Take[First[NIntegrate`GaussRuleData[2 M, MachinePrecision]], M] - 1``.

Comment: @J.M. Neat! Unfortunately, this is no bottleneck. Still nice to know, thanks.

Comment: I know, I just did something relatively easy. :) As I said, addressing your actual problem will require much thought...

Comment: On another note, have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53)?

Comment: @J.M.no, didn't notice it. Thanks for the link.

Comment: The PolarPlot will generate much faster if you wrap the first argument in `Evaluate`.

Comment: "the `N[#, 30]` should prevent the `LinearSolve::luc` error but it doesn't" - can you explain this? What do you get if you apply ``LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[]`` to your matrix of basis functions?

Comment: @J.M. `LinearAlgebra`MatrixConditionNumber[Table[B[i, m]...` gives 2.63531*10^98 . My comment on the `N[#,30]` was to remind me that even with `N` the `LinearSolve::luc` error occured and that I had to use `SetPrecision[#,Infintiy]` to get rid of it.

Comment: @Heike Wow, 3.5 vs. 148.5 seconds. Thank you for the tip.

Comment: `2.63531*10^98`is pretty badly conditioned... you really need to come up with a different route.

Comment: Have you looked at the work of Maslen and Rockmore. See for example: %0 Journal Article
%A Kostelec, Peter J.
%A Maslen, David K.
%A Healy, Dennis M., Jr.
%A Rockmore, Daniel N.
%T Computational harmonic analysis for tensor fields on the two-sphere
%J J. Comput. Phys.
%V 162
%D 2000
%N 2
%P 514--535
%@ 0021-9991
%L MR1774265 (2001c:65172)
%R doi:10.1006/jcph.2000.6551
%U http://dx.doi.org/10.1006/jcph.2000.6551 And references therein?

Comment: Calculation of R involves general recursion that is not optimized in Mathematica. Try to use memoisation to avoid stack bloat when calculate R functions. R is defined recursively and recursive calls are not even in the tail position.
Another advice - look at using Compile for your numeric functions.

Comment: Is there a research paper or thesis where this code was applied?  I am interested to learn how you applied the Spherical Beselll function is relevant in the radiation equation solution.

Comment: @JoseECalderon It was first prsented by Flannery et al. 1980 (http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1980ApJ...236..598F). The code above was used in Röllig et al. 2013 (http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2013A%26A...549A..85R).

Comment: Surprised in over 6 years nobody mentioned you should `Expand` the recursive definition of `F[l_][g_, ω_][k_]` to make it evaluate faster. In my system

`F[l_][g_, ω_][k_] := F[l][g, ω][k] = -h[l][g, ω] F[l - 1][g, ω][k] - l^2 k^2 F[l - 2][g, ω][k] // Expand;`

improves the running time for L = 27 from over 10 seconds to under 2.