# Plotting intensity field function of albedo and optical depth using Fast Spherical Harmonics on radiative transfer

Tags: plotting

This code was written by Markus Roellig, and I'd like to mention that all credits should go to him. Please, [see this link to open his original writing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10767/fast-spherical-harmonics-radiative-transfer).

```
SphericalBesselI[0, 0] := SphericalBesselI[0, 0] = 1;
SphericalBesselI[l_, z_] := Sqrt[π/(2 z)] BesselI[l + 1/2, z];
σ[l_][g_] := g^l
h[l_][g_, ω_] := h[l][g, ω] = (2 l + 1) (1 - ω σ[l][g]);
F[0][g_, ω_][k_] := F[0][g, ω][k] = -h[0][g, ω];
F[1][g_, ω_][k_] := F[1][g, ω][k] = h[0][g, ω] h[1][g, ω] - k^2;
F[l_][g_, ω_][k_] := F[l][g, ω][k] = -h[l][g, ω] F[l - 1][g, ω][k] -
  l^2 k^2 F[l - 2][g, ω][k];
kEV::mmatch = "Inconsistent list of Eigenvalues.";
kEV[list_List][m_Integer] := Module[{pos, neg},
   pos = Select[Sort@list, Positive];
   neg = Select[Sort@list, Negative];
   If[(Length[pos] == Length[neg]) && m <= Length[pos],
     If[Positive[m], pos[[m]], neg[[m]]],
     Message[kEV::mmatch]; $Failed]];
calculateEigenvalues[L_][g_, ω_] := 
   NSolve[F[L][g, ω][k] == 0, k][[All, 1, 2]];
R[0, m_][g_, ω_][k_] := R[0, m][g, ω][k] = 1;
R[1, m_][g_, ω_][k_] := R[1, m][g, ω][k] = (1 - ω)/k[m];
R[l_Integer, m_Integer][g_, ω_][k_] /; m < 0 := R[l, m][g, ω][k] = (-1)^l R[l, -m][g, ω][k]
R[l_Integer, m_][g_, ω_][k_] :=  R[l, m][g, ω][k] = 
     1/(l k[m]) (h[l - 1][g, ω] R[l - 1, m][g, ω][
      k] - (l - 1) k[m] R[l - 2, m][g, ω][k]);
getAngles[M_Integer] := 
 Sort@Select[
 List @@ (NRoots[LegendreP[2 M, x] == 0, x] /. Equal[_, x_] :> x), 
 Negative] 
B[i_Integer, m_Integer][g_?NumberQ, ω_?NumberQ][Lmax_, 
   taumax_?NumberQ, k_, angles_] := 
   Sum[(2 l + 1) R[l, m][g, ω][k] LegendreP[l, 
   angles[[i]]] SphericalBesselI[l, k[m] taumax], {l, 0, Lmax}];

createSphericalHarmonics[g_, ω_, I0_, tauMax_, L_?OddQ] := 
 Module[
  {M = (L + 1)/2, angles, eigenvalues, kEigenValues, AList},
angles = -SetPrecision[getAngles[M], Infinity];
eigenvalues = 
    SetPrecision[calculateEigenvalues[L][g, ω], Infinity];
 AList = LinearSolve[
     N[SetPrecision[
        Table[B[i, m][g, ω][L, tauMax, kEV[eigenvalues], angles], 
              {i, 1, M}, {m, 1, M}]
      , Infinity], 30], 
     N[SetPrecision[ConstantArray[I0, M], Infinity], 30]];

 {
  Function[tau, 
   Sum[AList[[m]] R[0, m][g, ω][
   kEV[eigenvalues]] SphericalBesselI[
   0, (tauMax - tau) kEV[eigenvalues][m]], {m, 1, M}]],
  Function[{tau, mu},
   Sum[(2 l + 1) LegendreP[l, mu] Sum[
   AList[[m]] R[l, m][g, ω][
     kEV[eigenvalues]] SphericalBesselI[
     l, (tauMax - tau) kEV[eigenvalues][m]], {m, 1, M}], {l, 0, L}]]
  }
 ]
```

By modifying the above code, [Fast Spherical Harmonics radiative transfer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/10767/fast-spherical-harmonics-radiative-transfer), I am trying to plot intensity field, function of albedo (omega) and optical depth (tau) at theta angle = 0, using ContourPlot, but no luck yet. I can't figure out what I did wrong. Here is what I edit at the end of what your wrote.

```
omegafunction[omega_] := {meanIntensity, intensity} = createSphericalHarmonics[0.5, omega, 1., 10, 19];
ContourPlot[meanIntensity[tau]/meanIntensity[0], {tau, 0, 10}, {omega, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, All}]
```

Any help will be very appreciable. Thank you.

Comment: You should share the definition of `createSphericalHarmonics` and other constants too, so people can try to reproduce your problem.

Comment: Hi MarcoB, Thank you so much for your comment. I edited my question as you suggest. Hope I can get some comments from other experts. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a typo: do you want to divide intensity by meanintensity?

Anyways, one way to do what you want is to tabulate your results and use ListContourPlot. Note that the computation fails for omega=1:

```
data = ParallelTable[Table[
{meanIntensity, intensity} = createSphericalHarmonics[0.5, omega, 1., 10, 19];
{tau,omega,Evaluate[intensity[tau, omega]/meanIntensity[0]]}, 
 {tau, 0, 1, .1}], {omega, 0, .9, 0.05}];
ListContourPlot[Flatten[data, 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Markus Roelling, It's an honor to receive a feedback from you who wrote the original code. Yes, it was a type and I fixed it.. This is the one I've been looking for. I appreciate your help.