# Why doesn't my code compile?

Tags: compile

```
Clear["`*"];
cf = Compile[{{A, _Real, 2}, {n, _Integer}},
   With[{a = A[[1]], b = A[[2]], c = A[[3]]},
    If[n < 1, {{a, b, c}},
      Join[cf[{a, (a + b)/2, (a + c)/2}, n - 1],
       cf[{(b + a)/2, b, (b + c)/2}, n - 1],
       cf[{(c + a)/2, (c + b)/2, c}, n - 1]
       ]
     ];
    ]
   ];

cf[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .8}} // N, 3]
```

This code I wrote can't be compiled, *Mathematica* returns

```
CompiledFunction::cfex: Could not complete external evaluation at instruction 19; proceeding with uncompiled evaluation. >>
```

How can I correctly compile it?

The uncompiled version:

```
Clear["`*"];
f[{a_, b_, c_}, n_] :=
  If[n < 1, {{a, b, c}},
   Join[f[{a, (a + c)/2, (a + b)/2}, n - 1],
    f[{(b + a)/2, b, (b + c)/2}, n - 1],
    f[{(c + a)/2, (c + b)/2, c}, n - 1]]
   ];

n = 3;
data = f[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .8}} // N, n];
ListLinePlot[data /. {a_, b_, c_} :> {a, b, c, a}]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if it is possible to compile such a **recursive** function.

Comment: There are several problems with your function: think about what is the type of the return value.  What rank tensor is it.  I can't really figure out what you're trying to achieve so I can't correct it for you, but: 1. as it is, your function doesn't return anything because of the `;` 2. if we fix that, it returns a rank 3 tensor which is fed back as input after a transformation.  The input is expected to be a rank 2 tensor however.  I'd suggest to first write an uncompiled version and fix the bugs.

Comment: @JacobAkkerboom I thought for a moment I could game that restriction, but it seems I was wrong.  So I agree, that's the main restriction here.  What I pointed out is secondary.

Comment: [Here](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/Compile/tutorial/Operation.html) it's shown how to create a recursive compiled function, but it relies in MainEvaluate so I'm not sure how much compilation would help with efficiency, unless the non-recursive part is substantial.

Comment: Related: [(13504)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13504/121), [(31171)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31171/121)

Comment: @Szabolcs Thank you, updated now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a compiled version. First note, however, that your compiled version and the top level version are not the same.

```
ClearAll[cf]
cf = Compile[{{A, _Real, 2}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   Block[{a = A[[1]], b = A[[2]], c = A[[3]]},
    If[n < 1, A,
     Join[cf[{a, (a + c)/2, (a + b)/2}, n - 1], 
      cf[{(b + a)/2, b, (b + c)/2}, n - 1], 
      cf[{(c + a)/2, (c + b)/2, c}, n - 1]]
     ]
    ]
   ];
```

This is called via (see further down):

```
dc = Partition[cf[input, n], 3];
```

A slightly different version that does not need an additional `Partition`

```
ClearAll[cf2]
cf2 = Compile[{{A, _Real, 2}, {n, _Integer}}, 
   Block[{a = A[[1]], b = A[[2]], c = A[[3]]},
    If[n < 1, {A},
     Join[cf2[{a, (a + c)/2, (a + b)/2}, n - 1], 
      cf2[{(b + a)/2, b, (b + c)/2}, n - 1], 
      cf2[{(c + a)/2, (c + b)/2, c}, n - 1]]
     ]
    ]
   , {{cf2[_, _], _Real, 3}}
   ];
```

For a comparison:

```
n = 10;
input = Developer`ToPackedArray[N[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {.5, .8}}]];
AbsoluteTiming[dc = Partition[cf[input, n], 3];]
AbsoluteTiming[dc2 = cf2[input, n];]
AbsoluteTiming[data = f[input, n];]
data === dc === dc2

(*
0.18
0.18
0.71
True
*)
```

Also, a better way to rearrange the data is:

```
data[[All, {1, 2, 3, 1}]]
```

which does not unpack.

```
ListLinePlot[data[[All, {1, 2, 3, 1}]]]
```

If you look at the compiled code with `CompilePrint` you will note that there are calls to `CopyTensor` - with some clever computed array (by direct assignment of the recursive cf calls into an array in stead of using `Join`) it may be possible to avoid those and save computational expense.

Hope this helps.