# How to speed up recursive compiled functions?

Tags: compile

I'm trying to speed up the recursive function that calculates [Rotation numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circle_map):

```
ClearAll[θ]
θ[n_, Ω_, k_] := θ[n, Ω, k] = θ[n - 1, Ω, k] + Ω - 
   k/(2 π) Sin[2 π θ[n - 1, Ω, k]]
θ[0, Ω_, k_] := 0
```

Notice that I'm using memoization.
Here's the timing of the uncompiled function:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[θ[n, .2, 1]/n, {n, 1, 1000}];]
```

> ```
> {0.016223, Null}
> ```

Now I tried compiling the recursive function:

```
ClearAll[compθ]
compθ = 
 Compile[{{n, _Integer}, {Ω, _Real}, {k, _Real}},
  If[n == 0, 0,
   compθ[n - 1, Ω, k] + Ω - k/(2 π)Sin[2 π compθ[n - 1, Ω, k]]],
  {{compθ[_, _, _], _Real}}, 
  CompilationOptions -> {"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True, 
    "ExpressionOptimization" -> True}, RuntimeOptions -> {"Speed"}]
```

The timing of the compiled function is worse:

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[compθ[n, .2, 1]/n, {n, 1, 1000}];]
```

> ```
> {0.342844, Null}
> ```

Of course the timing could be improved if I could somehow use memoization with the compiled function, but I couldn't find any example that shows how to do it. Is it possible? I also noticed with `CompilePrint` that the compiled function calls MainEvaluate, which is probably slowing the computation, but [this comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/compiling-a-recursive-formula#comment61272_13509) suggests that this may be unavoidable. Is this true?

Answer (score 5):

If you're looking for a faster way to calculate rotation numbers rather than optimizing your original function using memorization, try this:

```
AbsoluteTiming[ans1 = Table[θ[n, .2, 1]/n, {n, 1, 100000}];]

θ2 = Compile[{n, Ω, k}, Rest@NestList[# + Ω - k/(2 π) Sin[2 π #] &, 0, n]/Range@n];
ans2 = θ2[100000, 0.2, 1]; // AbsoluteTiming

And @@ (ans2 - ans1 // Chop // PossibleZeroQ)
```

> ```
> {0.414000, Null}
> {0.043000, Null}
> True
> ```

Notice that different computing method has caused slightly different result but I think it doesn't hurt.

As to your original method, AFAIK, there's no way to compile the structure `f[n_] := f[n] = …`. The only thing I can think of to optimize it is to compile the compilable part only:

```
f = Compile[{p, Ω, k}, p + Ω - k/(2 π) Sin[2 π p]];
θ3[n_, Ω_, k_] := θ3[n, Ω, k] = f[θ3[n - 1, Ω, k], Ω, k]
θ3[0, Ω_, k_] := 0
```

but this only speeds up the calculation for a specific set of parameters only once.

Answer (score 2):

Faster to use cycle in compiled functions

```
compθ2=Compile[{{n,_Integer},{Ω,_Real},{k,_Real}},
Module[{i=0,next=0.},
For[i=1,i<=n,i++,
next=next+Ω-k/(2*Pi)*Sin[2*Pi*next];
];
next
],
CompilationOptions->{"InlineCompiledFunctions"->True,"ExpressionOptimization"->True},RuntimeOptions->{"Speed"}]
```

But its not faster than using memorization

```
AbsoluteTiming[Table[compθ2[n, .2, 1]/n, {n, 1, 1000}];]
(*{0.075004,Null}*)
AbsoluteTiming[Table[θ[n,.2,1]/n,{n,1,1000}];]
(*{0.027002,Null}*)
```

Comment: Interesting, on your computer the compiled code is about 2.8x slower than the uncompiled code, on my machine it's 7.6x slower.