# Compile, "global variables" and recursion

Tags: compile, recursion, localization

I am trying to do something similar to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/EcVmyZihWNM/J-FGt7NY9pcJ/), namely to make a `Compile`'d function `outer` that itself calls a `Compile`'d function `inner` which accesses a variable defined in `outer`. Copy-pasting the example Leonid gives in the link, I get no errors. However in my case, I want `inner` to be a recursive function.

So far I have tried (the functions are toy examples):

```
Clear[inner];
inner = Compile[ {{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},
If[i >= j, Return[], AppendTo[bag, list]; inner[i + 1, j]];
,CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> False} ]
```

and

```
Clear[outer];
outer = Compile[{{i, _Integer}},
Block[{list = Table[{0, 0}, {i}], bag},
bag = {list};
inner[1, i];
bag
]
, CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
"InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}
]
```

Trying to execute this last piece results in the error message:

```
Compile::cret : The type of return values in (...) are different.
Evaluation will use the uncompiled function.
```

I have a hard time interpreting the output of `CompilePrint` in this case, so I cannot pinpoint the error in order to move further with this. Since I am able to create compiled recursive functions just fine in general, and the link provides a "hack" to make `inner` see the variables in `outer`, I think it should be possible to do this, but perhaps not...

EDIT: I have verified that the lingering `MainEvaluate` is not due `AppendTo` or some-such, by making the function `inner` even more basic. I have also tried all possible combinations of `True`/`False` for the `CompilationOptions` for both `inner` and `outer` with no success. So it seems to me that it's possible to compile either a recursive function, or a compiled function modifying a "global" variable when called from another compiled function, but not both =(

Comment: As far as I know, so far it's not possible to define a recursive compiled function. ([This question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/55206/1871) is slightly related.) I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: What about this? `LevelsNeeded=Compile[
{{b,_Integer},{M,_Integer},{x,_Integer}},
If[M<=(x*b+Quotient[x(x-1),2]),x,LevelsNeeded[b,M,x+1]]
,{{_LevelsNeeded,_Integer}}
,CompilationOptions->{"InlineExternalDefinitions"->True,"InlineCompiledFunctions"->False}
,CompilationTarget->"C",RuntimeOptions->"Speed"
];` If I call this **twice**, I see no MainEvaluate-calls, and it's very fast.

Comment: Quite interesting! BTW, the code can be simplified to `LevelsNeeded = 
  Compile[{{b, _Integer}, {M, _Integer}, {x, _Integer}}, 
   If[M <= (x*b + Quotient[x (x - 1), 2]), x, 
    LevelsNeeded[b, M, x + 1]], {{_LevelsNeeded, _Integer}}, 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}, 
   CompilationTarget -> C];`.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Compile recursive function modifying global variables](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31171/89).

Comment: @IstvánZachar Yes, it's virtually the same question. Have you been able to make it work?

Comment: @Marius No, unfortunately. My usual approach nowadays is to just write computation-intense code in C and only do top level or data-analysis under _Mathematica_.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work. Use `With` to "inject" the `inner` definition into `outer`.

```
Clear[inner];
inner = Compile[{{i, _Integer}, {j, _Integer}},
   If[i >= j,
    0,
    AppendTo[bag, list];
    inner[i + 1, j]]];

Clear[outer];
outer = With[{inner = inner}, Compile[{{i, _Integer}},
    Block[{list = ConstantArray[0, {i, 2}], bag},
     bag = {list};
     inner[1, i];
     bag]]];

In[123]:= outer[5]

(* Out[123]= {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0,
    0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}} *)
```

There may of course be other variants that work e.g. using the inline capabilities of `Compile`. I did not have success going that route but maybe was doing something not quite right. And `Compile` can be grumpy at times. [Edit: but see full edit below.]

---

#### Edit

This version seems sleeker. Still unable to avoid external evaluation though.

```
Clear[inner];
inner[i_, j_] :=
 If[i >= j,
  0,
  AppendTo[bag, list];
  inner[i + 1, j]]
Clear[outer];
outer = Compile[{{i, _Integer}},
   Block[{list = ConstantArray[0, {i, 2}], bag},
    bag = {list};
    inner[1, i];
    bag],
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True, 
     "InlineCompiledFunctions" -> True}];

In[163]:= outer[5]

(* Out[163]= {{{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 
   0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 
   0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {0, 0}, {0,
    0}, {0, 0}, {0, 0}}} *)
```

I think to make it fast one needs to use `` Internal`StuffBag `` or some such. I don't see `AppendTo` as being good for speed.

Comment: But this still calls `MainEvaluate`……

Comment: The proper edit-trick is to do it the other way around. Wrap the code that contains a back-tick into two backticks. If your code ends in a backtick, you need to make a space between the closing two backticks, like in ``JLink` `` which is written as `''JLink' ''` (I used quotes here..)

Comment: @halirutan Thx.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Indeed, my plan was to switch to ``Internal`Bag`` after getting rid of calls to `MainEvaluate`, but I didn't want to clutter the problem description with this detail, as I don't have complete understanding of how to use `Bag`s under `Compile` yet (that's next on my TODO) ;)

Comment: Just to be clear, the call to `MainEvaluate` does not stem from using `AppendTo`, right?

Comment: I believe you are correct that `AppendTo` is not a big issue. Actually I learned to my dismay that `Compile` has issues with `ConstantArray` so you might get better behavior with `Table` there. As for using ``Internal`Bag``, I look forward to any usable result you might obtain (I tried and fell flat).