# Speeding up compilation of recursive functions

Tags: compile, recursion

I am trying to understand how to speed up recursive functions via compilation. I am experimenting with the Fibonacci sequence (though this is not really what I want to do eventually). Can somebody explain why these different versions of the functions have different computational speeds?

```
In[2]:= num = 30;

In[3]:= Table[Fibonacci[i], {i, 1, num}]

Out[3]= {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 610, \
987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025, \
121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040}

In[4]:= fib = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[
    {},
    Which[n == 0, 0, n == 1, 1, True, fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]]], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

In[5]:= RepeatedTiming@Table[fib[i], {i, 1, num}]

Out[5]= {5.449, {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377, 
  610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 75025,
   121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040}}

In[6]:= fibW = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[
    {},
    Which[n == 0, 0, n == 1, 1, True, fibW[n - 1] + fibW[n - 2]]
    ]
   ];

In[7]:= RepeatedTiming@Table[fibW[i], {i, 1, num}]

Out[7]= {1.3769, {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377,
   610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 
  75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040}}

In[8]:= fibWC = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[
    {},
    Which[n == 0, 0, n == 1, 1, True, fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]]
    ], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

In[9]:= RepeatedTiming@Table[fibWC[i], {i, 1, num}]

Out[9]= {0.1071, {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377,
   610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 
  75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040}}

In[10]:= fibWC1 = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[
    {},
    Which[n == 0, 0, n == 1, 1, True, fib[n - 1] + fib[n - 2]]
    ], 
   CompilationTarget -> "C", 
   CompilationOptions -> {"InlineExternalDefinitions" -> True}
   ];

In[11]:= RepeatedTiming@Table[fibWC1[i], {i, 1, num}]

Out[11]= {5.467, {1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55, 89, 144, 233, 377,
   610, 987, 1597, 2584, 4181, 6765, 10946, 17711, 28657, 46368, 
  75025, 121393, 196418, 317811, 514229, 832040}}
```

In particular,  fibW is faster than fib, which indicates that compilation to C does not help. But then, fibWC is much faster than fibW and fibWC1,(whihc inlines external definitions, but is otherwise the same as fibWC) on the otherhand is much slower.

I am wondering what is happening behind the scenes and in the end what is the best way to compile.

Comment: This is weird. I can confirm such varying timings when running this on a fresh kernel. But when I compile all the functions _twice_ after a kernel restart and check the timings, then `fib`, `fibWC`, and `fibWC1` are rather closed together and approximately 16 times as fast as `fibW`.

Comment: Your functions `fibWC` and `fibWC1` call `fib[]`... Shouldn't that be `fibWC` and `fibWC1`, respectively?

Comment: In general, support for compiling recursive functions in _Mathematica_ is quite limited.

Answer (score 5):

With

```
CompiledFunctionTools`CompilePrint@fib
```

you will see that `fib` calls `MainEvaluate` in order to call itself recursively. As the `CompilationTarget` is set to `"C"`, this means that certain code for the communication with the MathKernel is injected into the C-code for `fib`. This code gets compiled into a `LibraryFunction` automatically. At runtime, every call from the `LibraryFunction` behind `fib` to `MainEvaluate` means that the library function has to wait for the MathKernel to process this call.

You can show the produced code with

```
ExportString[fib, "C"]
```

The pseudocode of `fibW` is the same as that of `fib` but the `CompilationTarget` is now the Wolfram Virtual Machine (`"WVM"`). Code compiled into `"WVM"` is usually not as fast as code compiled to `"C"`, but as it is still somewhat on the Mathematica side, the communication with the MathKernel tends to be a bit quicker (e.g., see [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13504/compiling-a-recursive-formula)).

Personally, I would suggest that you abandon the idea of recursion and use a plain, simple loop in C, instead. This will produce the first 30 Fibonacci numbers 70000 times faster than `fibWC`.

```
fibC = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
   Module[{a, x, y, z},
    a = Table[1, {i, 1, n}];
    x = 1;
    y = 1;
    Do[z = x + y; a[[i]] = z; x = y; y = z;, {i, 3, n}];
    a
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```