# Only perform a symbolic differentiation once

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, performance-tuning, symbolic, special-functions, memoization

I want to define a function that involves a differentiation step that *Mathematica* can do easily, which might be of the form

```
f[a_,b_,z_,j_]:=D[Hypergeometric1F1[a, b, z^2], {z, 2 j}]
```

(This will not work when given numeric `z`, but that is only a small part of the problem.)

I will be using this for a limited set of `j`'s quite intensively in `z`. It is therefore important to me that the symbolic differentiation only take place once, so that *Mathematica* is not repeatedly trying to do the same symbolic manipulations when running over a plot or a numerical integration.

What is the cleanest/most elegant way to do this sort of partial memoization procedure?

Comment: Maybe you can try and remove the `:` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks that doesn't do anything, but leave it symbolic form. There's not enough information to perform the derivative.

Comment: Have you tried to create a non global variable inside your function that stores the derivative? You could then use replacement rules to call upon the derivative.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A general approach in this kind of situations is to use memoization. Here, however, some of the parameters should remain patterns (general), so you can use something like this (see [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60/81) for a similar case):

```
ClearAll[f];
f[a_, b_, z_, j_] :=
   Block[{al, bl, zl},
     f[al_, bl_, zl_, j] = D[Hypergeometric1F1[al, bl, zl^2], {zl, 2 j}];
     f[a, b, z, j]
   ]
```

Upon the first call, a special global rule (definition) will be created for any specific `j`, and all subsequent calls with this `j` will use this definition:

```
f[a,b,z,1]

(* 
    (2 a Hypergeometric1F1[1+a,1+b,z^2])/b+(4 a (1+a) z^2 
      Hypergeometric1F1[2+a,2+b,z^2])/(b (1+b))
*)
```

Inspecting the definition now:

```
?f

Global`f
f[al$_,bl$_,zl$_,1]=(2 al$ Hypergeometric1F1[1+al$,1+bl$,zl$^2])/bl$+
    (4 al$ (1+al$) zl$^2 Hypergeometric1F1[2+al$,2+bl$,zl$^2])/(bl$ (1+bl$))

f[a_,b_,z_,j_]:=Block[{al,bl,zl},f[al_,bl_,zl_,j]=\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \({zl, 2\ j}\)]\(Hypergeometric1F1[al, bl, 
\*SuperscriptBox[\(zl\), \(2\)]]\)\);f[a,b,z,j]]
```

Comment: [Reminds me...](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60)

Comment: @J.M. Sure, that's the same pattern. I have added a link. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Just for fun, here is an explicit formula for the derivative:

```
f[a_,b_,z_,j_] := Sum[
    1/(j-k)! (2j)!/(2k)! 4^k Pochhammer[a,j+k]/Pochhammer[b,j+k] z^(2k) Hypergeometric1F1[a+j+k,b+j+k,z^2],
    {k,0,j}
]
```

Confirmation:

```
Table[D[Hypergeometric1F1[a, b, z^2], {z, 2j}] == f[a, b, z, j], {j, 20}]
```

> {True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, 
>   True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True}