# using a Mathematica function to define a new function

Tags: functions, meta-programming

I'd like to define a function of three variables which produces a new, named function of a single variable, where this final variable is not a member of the first three. So I'd like something where I have

```
f0[x_ , y_ , z_] := << complicated function >>
```

which gives `f1[p_]`. Furthermore, I'd like to have the functions be defined in such a way that when I write

```
IN:= f0[x0,y0,z0]
```

I get

```
OUT:= fx0y0z0[p_]
```

so that I can easily identify which inputs produced the function. So, basically, I'd like to wind up with a function produced via Interpolation and I'd like that function to have a specific name defined by my inputs.

For instance, let's say I'm creating a numerical function by writing down a table in two variables (say, `p` and `q`) that requires `x`, `y`, and `z` as inputs. Then I'd like to integrate over `q` and interpolate over `p` so that my final function is just a function over `q` only.

So, let's say that my first function is

```
g[x_,y_,z_,p_,q_] := (x + y + z) p / q
```

Now I'd like to tabulate this over `p` and `q` for given values of `x`, `y`, and `z`. Then I'd like to integrate over `p` and have a function of `q` only. I can for instance do the following

```
f1[x_,y_,z_] := NIntegrate[
  Interpolation[
    Flatten[Table[{q, p, 
       g[x,y,z,p,q]}, {p,p0,p1}, {q,q0,q1}],1]][#,
    p], {p, p0, p1}] &
```

and then this is a well-behaved function of `q` which I can make tables of, which I can then plot, integrate, etc. just by writing `f1[x0,y0,x0][q]`. But this is not very convenient for me since it requires me to write out a new function name every time I want to examine the behavior as a function of different values of `x`, `y`, and `z`, and I will ultimately need many values of `x`, `y`, and `z`. Is there any way to write a meta-function that is capable of producing a brand new interpolating function of q only, with the name including the input values of `x`, `y`, and `z`?

Comment: A solution like the one to [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21782/only-perform-a-symbolic-differentiation-once) might be useful to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I typically use pure functions for this type of meta programming. For example:

```
generator[p_,q_] := Function[{x,y,z},
  Evaluate[ 
    Integrate[ (x+y+z)/(p+q), {p,p0,p1},{q,q0,q1}]
  ]
]
```

Then one can use it as

```
fpXqY = generator[X,Y]
```

And then `fpXqY` will be a pure function you can use. This only works for function that can be treated as pure functions. However, one can also do something similar by just calling `SetDelayed[]` (which is the full form of `:=`) within your generator to create a new function. So something like:

```
generator2[p_,q_] := SetDelayed[ 
  ToExpression[ StringJoin[ "fp", ToString[p], "q", ToString[q]]][x_, y_, z_]
  , Integrate[ (x+y+z)/(p+q), {p,p0,p1},{q,q0,q1}]
]
```

And then call it as

```
generator2[X,Y]
```

and you should then find you can use `fpXqY` as your evaluator. Note that you can either use `Set` or `SetDelayed` as you need.

Comment: Thanks -- this seems to be on the right track. However, my goal is to produce a function with an entirely new name.

Say I have

g[x_,y_,z_,p_,q_]:=(x+y+z)p/q

f1[x_,y_,z_] := 
 NIntegrate[Interpolation[Flatten[Table[{q,p,g[x,y,z,p,q]},{p,10}, {q,10}],1]][#,p],{p,1,10}]&

as before. What is wrong with the following?

generator[x_,y_,z_]:=SetDelayed[ToExpression[ToString[StringForm["f1``````",x,y,z]]][#]&,Interpolation[Table[f1[x,y,z][p],{p,10}]]]

I'd like to produce, e.g.,

f1323 = Interpolation[Table[f1[3,2,3][x],{x,10}]];

which is easily identifiable and very fast. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @user1451632 right sorry, let me fix that -- see the updated generator 2. In general, you should avoid using `StringForm` for producing function names -- the `*Form` sometimes introduces odd quirks

Comment: Terrific! This really helps. Thank you for your time.