# List of Tribonacci Polynomials with Mathematica?

Tags: polynomials, recursion

I want to list top ten of Tribonacci polynomials. I have following algorithm, but it doesnt work.

```
Tribonacci[0] := 0 
Tribonacci[1] := 1
Tribonacci[2] := x^2
Tribonacci[3] := x^4 + x
Tribonacci[n_] := Tribonacci[n] = 
                  x^2 Tribonacci[n - 1] + x*Tribonacci[n - 2] +  Tribonacci[n - 3] 

Tribonacci /@ Range[5]

(* Out:= {1, x^2, x + x^4, 1 + x^3 + x^2 (x + x^4), 
          x^2 + x (x + x^4) + x^2 (1 + x^3 + x^2 (x + x^4))} *)
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's one way to define the series:

```
Clear[f];
f[n_] := f[n - 1] + f[n - 2] + f[n - 3];
f[1] = 1; f[2] = 1; f[3] = 1;
```

Now you can get any f

```
f[10]
```

gives the answer 105. Similarly, if you want to define the polynomials, you could set up a recursion

```
Clear[g];
g[n_] := x^2 g[n - 1] + x g[n - 2] + g[n - 3];
g[0] = 0; g[1] = 1; g[2] = x^2;
```

Now you can find the nth g by

```
 g[5]
```

which gives

```
 x^2 + x (x + x^4) + x^2 (1 + x^3 + x^2 (x + x^4))
```

which of course can be simplified using `Expand[g[5]]` or `FullSimplify[g[5]]` depending which you think is simpler. Apply to find the first 10 by `g/@Range[10]`

If this is going too slowly (for large n), you could add the memoization trick, which is very simple to do: instead of `f[n]` above, you could use

```
    f[n_] := f[n] = f[n - 1] + f[n - 2] + f[n - 3];
```

and now the lower numbers are cached (and hence subsequent calls are quicker). Same thing can be done with g[n].

Answer (score 2):

Using a technique discussed in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60), here's how you might define the "tribonacci" numbers/polynomials recursively:

```
SetAttributes[Tribonacci, Listable];
Tribonacci[0, x_] := 0;
Tribonacci[1, x_] := 1;
Tribonacci[2, x_] := x^2;
Tribonacci[n_Integer, x_] := Module[{al, xl}, 
   Set @@ Hold[Tribonacci[n, xl_], 
    Expand[xl^2 Tribonacci[n - 1, xl] + xl Tribonacci[n - 2, xl] + Tribonacci[n - 3, xl]]];
   Tribonacci[n, x]];
Tribonacci[n_Integer] := Tribonacci[n, 1]
```

Since I set the function to be `Listable`, it is now easy to generate a pile of these polynomials:

```
Tribonacci[Range[0, 10], t]
   {0, 1, t^2, t + t^4, 1 + 2 t^3 + t^6, 3 t^2 + 3 t^5 + t^8, 2 t + 6 t^4 + 4 t^7 + t^10,
    1 + 7 t^3 + 10 t^6 + 5 t^9 + t^12, 6 t^2 + 16 t^5 + 15 t^8 + 6 t^11 + t^14,
    3 t + 19 t^4 + 30 t^7 + 21 t^10 + 7 t^13 + t^16,
    1 + 16 t^3 + 45 t^6 + 50 t^9 + 28 t^12 + 8 t^15 + t^18}
```

Alternatively, you can use `LinearRecurrence[]` if you just want to generate the pile directly:

```
LinearRecurrence[{t^2, t, 1}, {0, 1, t^2}, 11] // Expand
```

Another alternative is to use `DifferenceRoot[]` in the definition of `Tribonacci[]`:

```
Tribonacci[n_Integer, x_] :=
   DifferenceRoot[Function[{y, k}, {y[k] == x^2 y[k - 1] + x y[k - 2] + y[k - 3],
                                    y[0] == 0, y[1] == 1, y[2] == x^2}]][n]
```

Comment: See [this article](http://www.fq.math.ca/Scanned/11-5/hoggatt.pdf) if you want more information on $n$-nacci polynomials in general.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[t];
t[n_] := x^2*t[n - 1] + x*t[n - 2] + t[n - 3];
t[0] := 0; t[1] := 1; t[2] := x^2; t[3] := x^4 + x;
```

The above equations are the definition of the Tribonacci polynomials.

To print some elements of Tribonacci sequence;

```
Table[Expand[t[i]], {i, 0, 5}]
```

Comment: You skipped `t[3]`. Also, you should space out you definitions a bit more for readability; putting them on separate lines, generally, works well.

Comment: @rcollyer, you were right. I changed it.

Comment: Incidentally, the grave marks ( ` ) only perform _inline_ code formatting. To put into block form, precede each line with four spaces, and don't wrap it in the grave marks. Look at my [revisions](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/posts/25328/revisions) to see what I mean.

Comment: @rcollyer, you don't need to specify t[3]... it can be calculated from the previous three terms.

Comment: @bills true, but he had `f[4] := x^4 + x`. Of course, he's missing a few terms ...

Comment: @rcollyer and bills . i know it is unnecessary to specify t[3]. I gave it since it was given by ösnur östunc. i didnt want to arrage the problem.