# Keeping memory to reduce the running time of recursion

Tags: recursion, memory

I am using the following recursion in Mathematica to compute `W[n, 1, s]` for given n and s:

```
W[1, j_, s_] := B[j, s]
W[n_, j_, s_] := W[n, j, s] = Sum[A[i, s] W[n-1,j+1-i], {i,0,j}]
```

with functions A and B given. I need the value of `W[n, 1, s]`   for n equal to 2 to some k, and for different values of s. So as you can see I have written the recursion in a way so that it remembers the values it finds with the goal of reducing the time by keeping more memory. However, for higher values of k the computer runs out of memory.
Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53)?

Comment: Could you please define the functions `A` and `B`?

Comment: They are complicated Laplace transforms (s is the Laplace variable) defined in terms of other LTs (H and X) which are available in closed form. e.g., `B[i_, s_] := 
 If[i == 0, ((\[Mu]/(\[Mu] + \[Lambda] + s)) p H[s])/(1 \
- X[s]), ((\[Mu]/(\[Mu] + \[Lambda] + s)) p H[s] \
(X[s])^(i - 1))/((1 - X[s]))^(i + 1)]`

Comment: Thanks @J. M. I am reading it and I am getting some good ideas.