# Numerical evaluation of ChebyshevT

Tags: numerics, polynomials, special-functions

When I evaluate the following Chebyshev series of the first kind in two different ways, I get two very different results:

```
N[ChebyshevT[100, Cos[Pi/7]], 8]
N[ChebyshevT[100, Cos[Pi/7]]]

Out[1] = 0.62348980
Out[2] = 3.71097*10^18
```

Clearly the first result is the correct one. Could someone please explain why the difference occurs e.g. is it perhaps because of a peculiar way that the long Chebyshev polynomial is numerically evaluated? The problem does not arise for shorter length Chebyshev polynomials.

Comment: Numerical instability. `N` without any precision specified works in machine precision with precision tracking switched off. For high-order polynomials, this is a bad idea. When a precision is specified, the working precision is adjusted so as to ensure that all of the requested digits are correct.

Comment: Note also that `ChebyshevT[100, N@Cos[Pi/7]]` is accurate and fast, no doubt because stable algorithms are used to compute built-in functions with machine precision *inputs.*

Comment: @OleksandrR. thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @MichaelE2: yes, I had noticed that but was not sure why Mathematica did not treat N[f(x)] the same as f(N[x]).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to evaluate `ChebyshevT` polynomials accurately you can consider using the Chebyshev recurrence, using memoization.

```
T[0,x_]:=1;
T[1,x_]:=x;
T[n_,x_]:= T[n,x]=2*x*T[n-1,x]-T[n-2,x];
```

This should be fast and stable.  If you are doing a lot of these,
rearranging the computation working from the low index upward would make memoization unnecessary.  Using this recurrence for symbol x is probably a bad idea though.

Try `T[100, N[Cos[Pi/7]]]`  though.

Comment: You might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53)…