# Sudden truncation of numerical series expansion

Tags: numerics, interpolation, series-expansion

Start with

```
H = q[t]^2 + p[t]^2 + q[t]^3
A = D[H, p[t]]
B = -D[H, q[t]]
NDSolve[{q'[t] == A, p'[t] == B, q[0] == p[0] == .2}, {q[t], 
    p[t]}, {t, 0, 5}] // First;
R = Evaluate[{q[t], p[t]} /. %]
```

This gives

```
>> {InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>][t], InterpolatingFunction[{{0., 5.}}, <>][t]}
```

Which looks like

```
ParametricPlot[R, {t, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

[image].

Now, take

```
Series[R, {t, 0, 10}] // Normal
```

which gives

```
{0.2 + 0.4 t - 2.08063 t^2 + 8477.23 t^3, 
 0.2 - 0.52 t - 2.5593 t^2 + 10427.5 t^3} .
```

Something is utterly wrong, here. This should be an infinite polynomial. I don't even have to plot it to know it won't, obviously, approximate my original interpolating function correctly.

**Edit:**

1. Is there a maximum number of derivatives one can take from an interpolating function? Why the sudden truncation? - Answered in the comments.
2. Is there a way to circumvent this?

Comment: An `InterpolatingFunction` interpolates between points _precicely_ by using interpolating polynomials. The default order seems to be 3 (but I don't know if there are cases where _Mathematica_ automatically uses a higher or lower order), explaining why your `Series` truncate after `t^3`.

Comment: @MariusLadegårdMeyer That's valuable info. I'll update my question, but thank you very much!

Comment: For an answer to your second question: [probably not](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13836/the-only-usage-for-the-option-interpolationorder-in-ndsolve-is-to-be-set-to-all).

Comment: Using `InterpolationOrder -> All` in `NDSolve` will yield an interpolation with an order equal to the order of the step (which is variable with the default method).  It still won't be of order 10.

Comment: Using the Bulirsch-Stoer method (`Method -> "Extrapolation"`) in conjunction with Michael's advice should net you a few more coefficients, but maybe not as many as you'd like.

Comment: You might also be interested in using the Picard iteration; [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89374) by Jens is a particularly nice implementation.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. Still weird to me the fact that this question has got so many close votes. I think I don't understand how this community works, yet.

Comment: @QuantumBrick `InterpolationOrder` is in the base documentation of `NDSolve[]` and such this question is at risk of closure. There have also been multiple votes not to close this question as the solution isn't as obvious as many others that get closed for this reason.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might use `FunctionInterpolation` to re-interpolate to a higher order:

```
g = FunctionInterpolation[R[[1]], {t, 0, 4}, InterpolationOrder -> 6]
```

then you get a higher order series approximation:

```
s[t_] = Series[g[t], {t, 0, 6}] // Normal
```

> 0.2 + 0.456923 t - 0.780614 t^2 - 0.132724 t^3 + 0.325397 t^4 - 
>    0.078419 t^5

```
Show[{
  Plot[R[[1]], {t, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Red], Plot[s[t], {t, 0, 4}]}, 
   PlotRange -> {-1.5, 1}]
```

[image]

note the cubic series (green line) is really poor, since its only good over the first increment from `NDSolve` which is ~0.00012

the parametric form:

```
s[t_] = {Series[FunctionInterpolation[#, {t, 0, 4},
        InterpolationOrder -> 10][t], {t, 0, 20}] // Normal} & /@ R
Show[{
  ParametricPlot[R, {t, 0, 3.546}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.02], Red}],
  ParametricPlot[s[t], {t, 0, 3.546}, PlotStyle -> Blue]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There are higher order methods available in `NDSolve`, for example [`"ImplicitRungeKutta"`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NDSolveImplicitRungeKutta.html).

```
H = q[t]^2 + p[t]^2 + q[t]^3;
A = D[H, p[t]];
B = -D[H, q[t]];
NDSolve[{q'[t] == A, p'[t] == B, q[0] == p[0] == .2},
   {q[t], p[t]}, {t, 0, 5}, 
   Method -> {"ImplicitRungeKutta", "DifferenceOrder" -> 10}, (* for degree 10 polys *) 
   InterpolationOrder -> All] // First;
R = Evaluate[{q[t], p[t]} /. %];

Series[R, {t, 0, 10}] // Normal
(*
  {0.2 + 0.4 t - 0.52 t^2 - 0.425533 t^3 - 97.2464 t^4 + 
    3.83907*10^6 t^5 - 8.07936*10^10 t^6 + 9.74544*10^14 t^7 - 
    6.7802*10^18 t^8 + 2.5365*10^22 t^9 - 3.95812*10^25 t^10, 
   0.2 - 0.52 t - 0.64 t^2 + 0.392703 t^3 + 169.596 t^4 - 
    6.65809*10^6 t^5 + 1.40133*10^11 t^6 - 1.69034*10^15 t^7 + 
    1.17602*10^19 t^8 - 4.39952*10^22 t^9 + 6.86524*10^25 t^10}
*)
```

This has significant error in the higher degree terms. In part at least, this is due to expanding at `t == 0`, where `NDSolve` takes a few very small steps as it gets its bearings.  It behaves better in the interior:

```
ser = Series[R, {t, 1, 10}] // Normal
(*
  {-0.0105103 - 0.592927 (-1 + t) + 0.0206892 (-1 + t)^2 + 
     0.382821 (-1 + t)^3 - 0.18246 (-1 + t)^4 - 0.0667898 (-1 + t)^5 + 
     0.114268 (-1 + t)^6 - 0.0269471 (-1 + t)^7 - 0.0295921 (-1 + t)^8 - 
     0.0847381 (-1 + t)^9 + 1.31425 (-1 + t)^10,
   -0.296464 + 0.0206892 (-1 + t) + 0.574232 (-1 + t)^2 - 0.364921 (-1 + t)^3 - 
     0.166974 (-1 + t)^4 + 0.342808 (-1 + t)^5 - 0.0945715 (-1 + t)^6 - 
     0.123299 (-1 + t)^7 + 0.129194 (-1 + t)^8 - 2.51112 (-1 + t)^9 + 36.9119 (-1 + t)^10}
*)
```

The polynomials are accurate only over a few steps near the center of the series.  The method `Method -> "Extrapolation"` does quite a bit better, but sometimes with a lower degree than 10 (such as 8 or 9); however, it's still not accurate over the whole curve as george2079's method seems to be.  **But** one should keep in mind that the usual purpose of series is local approximation.