# Solving an unstable BVP numerically, accurately and efficiently

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, nonlinear

About two weeks ago I've posted the following question on MathOverflow:

[Solving a boundary value problem numerically, with high precision](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/259630/solving-a-boundary-value-problem-numerically-with-high-precision).

That is, the ODE is
\begin{equation}
y''=y^2-t \tag{1}
\end{equation}
and we're looking for the two slopes $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ such that the solutions $y_i$ with the initial conditions
\begin{align}
y_i(0)&=0 \\y_i'(0)&=\alpha_i \quad i=1,2
\end{align}
are asymptotic to $\sqrt{t}$ as $t \to +\infty$.

I've been trying to attack it myself for quite some time, and here's what I came up with:

Using the quadratic Taylor approximation based at a point $t_i$ we get
\begin{align}
y(t_{i+1}) & \approx y(t_i)+y'(t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i)+\frac{y''(t_i)}{2}(t_{i+1}-t_i)^2\\
&=y(t_i)+y'(t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i)+\frac{y^2(t_i)-t_i}{2}(t_{i+1}-t_i)^2
\end{align}
where I have used the ODE $(1)$ to reduce the final coefficient. Similarly one gets an approximation for the slope:
\begin{align}
y'(t_{i+1})& \approx y'(t_i)+y''(t_i)(t_{i+1}-t_i)\\
&=y'(t_i)+\left(y^2(t_i)-t_i \right)(t_{i+1}-t_i)
\end{align}

---

In Mathematica, I've implemented this "time step" as follows (The `Clip` command is used to avoid overflow)

```
QuadraticTaylor[{y_, p_, t_, dt_}] := {Clip[y + p dt + 1/2 (y^2 - t) dt^2, {-4, 4}],
p + (y^2 - t) dt, t + dt, dt};
```

Then after trying out different slopes I using the method in the interval $[0,10]$ with $N=10^5$ subintervals and $\alpha=0.92437$ results in a blowup. That is, the code

```
With[{Parabola = ContourPlot[x == y^2, {x, 0, 10}, {y, -5, 5},ContourStyle->Black]}, 
 Manipulate[T = NestList[QuadraticTaylor, {0, \[Alpha], 0, 10/N}, N]; 
  Show[Parabola, 
   ListPlot[Map[{#[[3]], #[[1]]} &, T]]], {{\[Alpha], 0.92437`}, -10, 
   10}, {{dt, 0.1}, 0, 1}, {{N, 10000}, 1, 1000000, 1}]]
```

produced the following plot

[image]

while using $\alpha=0.92436$ resulted in an undershoot.

[image]

Thus, I thought that one of the critical slopes lies in the interval $[0.92436,0.92437]$. However, using a higher degree Taylor approximation (which I could only do with fewer subintervals, since the evaluations are computationally more expensive), it looks like the interval is actually
$$[0.92437548,0.92437549] .$$

Here I'm at a point in which I'm not sure what is the optimal tradeoff between the degree of the Taylor approximation, and the number of subintervals $N$. Moreover, these calculations take a pretty long time (over a minute) for $N>10^6$.

---

I'd love to hear your thoughts on my attempt, also, if you know a better way to do this please let me know! I'd like to get at least 16 decimal digits on *both* of the $\alpha$s (my attempt only discusses the positive $\alpha$). Thank you!

P.S. I've also tried using NDSolve to do this, but I'm not sure on how to tweak the settings to best fit my problem. Using default settings seems to get the 7th digit wrong.

Comment: "numerically, accurately and efficiently" - this feels like one of those situations where you can only pick two out of three... in the meantime, you might be interested in [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/89374).

Comment: why do you call this BVP? You have initial conditions both at zero?

Comment: @Nasser the problem is fundamentally a BVP, relating the behaviour of the function $y(t)$ at $t=0$ and $t=\infty$. I tried solving it using a [shooting method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shooting_method) which reduces it to an IVP.

Comment: But you haven't transform the ode, why only the bcs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's somewhat surprising that

1. brute-force attack turns out to be a good enough solution:

   ```
   {inf = 20, pre = 32};
   pa = ParametricNDSolveValue[{y''[x] == y@x^2 - x, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == alpha}, 
      y, {x, 0, inf}, alpha, MaxSteps -> Infinity, WorkingPrecision -> pre];

   {i = 5, init = 92437/10^5};

   (alphavalue = 
      NestWhile[If[pa[# + 10^(-i)][inf] < Sqrt[inf], # + 10^(-i), i++; #] &, init, 
    i <= Floor[pre/2] &] // Quiet) // AbsoluteTiming    
   (* {36.075637, 9243754874375653/10000000000000000} *)    

   p1 = Plot[#, {x, 0, 20}] &@{x^(1/2), pa[alphavalue][x], 
         pa[alphavalue + 10^-(pre/2)][x]} // Quiet
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]
2. `FindRoot` seems not to work well on this problem.
3. though it doesn't help much in finding an accurate enough $\alpha$, finite difference method (FDM) does a good job in solving the BVP. I'll use [`pdetoae`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/127997/1871) for the generation of difference equations:

   ```
   points = 25;
   grid = Array[# &, points, {0, inf}];
   difforder = 4;
   (* Definition of pdetoae isn't included in this code piece,
      please find it in the link above. *)
   ptoa = pdetoae[y[x], grid, difforder];
   set = {y''[x] == y@x^2 - x, y[0] == 0, y[inf] == Sqrt[inf]};
   ae = MapAt[#[[2 ;; -2]] &, ptoa@set, 1];

   sollst = 
     FindRoot[ae, {y/@ grid, Sqrt[grid]}\[Transpose], WorkingPrecision -> 32][[All, -1]];
   sol = ListInterpolation[sollst, grid, InterpolationOrder -> difforder];

   sol'[0]
   (* 1.019443775765894394411167742141 <- Not accurate at all. 
      This can be improved by using a larger points and difforder,
      but not quite economic. *)
   (* However, the solution i.e. value of y is accurate enough: *)
   p2 = Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, inf}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick, Dashed}];
   Show[p1, p2]
   ```

   [image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: So what you are trying to say is that, there will be blow up/down using MMA?

Comment: @mmm To be precise, the solution will blow up/undershoots using any software,  if we're solving the equation with initial condition $y(0)=0,\ y'(0)\approx0.92436$. The solution is extremely sensitive to initial value $y'(0)$. ("$α=0.92437$ results in a blowup, $α=0.92436$ resulted in an undershoot. " ) And if I understand the question correctly, an accurate enough $\alpha$ (rather than a stable solution) is exactly what OP needs.

Comment: In my comment, I have  argued that, Maple is able to solve the BVP without any problem, "numerically, accurately and efficiently".

Comment: @MMM Yeah, I saw it, but can a accurate enough $y'(0)$ be calculated from the solution given by _Maple_?

Comment: Maple gives `alpha=0.924375469638557'.

Comment: BTW, I like the FDM solution. Thanks for that.

Comment: @mmm You're welcome. BTW what if you set a higher precision in _Maple_?

Comment: How hard I try in maple, I get the same `alpha` as mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks, I like the brute force approach. However, my understanding is that WorkingPrecision->n is supposed to give n correct digits. If that is the case why did you use twice the amount (in pre=32)?

Comment: @user1337 According to the **Details** of document of `WorkingPrecision`: "Setting `WorkingPrecision->n` causes all *internal computations* to be done to at most n‐digit precision." "Even if internal computations are done to n‐digit precision, the *final results* you get may have much lower precision." So we may need a `WorkingPrecision` higher than `16` to get `16` correct digits in the result. I choose `32` because according to the **Details** of `NDSolve`, …

Comment: …"`NDSolve` adapts its step size so that the estimated error in the solution is just within the tolerances specified by `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`." "The default setting of `Automatic` for `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` is equivalent to `WorkingPrecision/2`." At this point, one may think we can set `WorkingPrecision->16, AccuracyGoal->16,PrecisionGoal->16` instead of `WorkingPrecision->32`, but I decided not to touch `AccuracyGoal` and `PrecisionGoal` because of the reason mentioned in this post: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/118249/1871

Answer (score 6):

**Comment**

**Solving IVP**

I have converted your `BVP` in to a `IVP`, like this,

$$y1^{'}(t)=y2(t),\,\, y2^{'}(t)=y1^{2}(t)-t,\,\, y1(0)=y10, \,\,y2(0)=y20$$

Now, I will try to solve the above system for a set `{y10,y20}` of initial conditions,

```
soln[y10_?NumericQ, y20_?NumericQ] :=First@NDSolve[{y1'[t]==y2[t],y2'[t]-y1[t]^2 + t == 0, 
y1[0] == y10, y2[0] == y20}, {y1, y2}, {t, 0, 5}];
Plot[Evaluate[{y1[t], y2[t]} /. soln[#, #] & /@Range[-1.5, 0.4, 0.1]], {t, 0, 5}, 
PlotRange -> All,PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, AxesLabel -> {"t", "y"},
PlotLegends -> {"y1", "y2"}]

ParametricPlot[Evaluate[{y1[t], y2[t]} /. soln[#, #] & /@Range[-1.5, 0.4, 0.1]], {t, 0, 3},
PlotRange -> All,PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}, AxesLabel -> {"y1", "y2"}]
```

Doing different experimentation with initial conditions, it is evident that the solution blowup when `{y10,y20}>0.4`, i.e., `Range[0.4, 2, 0.1]`.

**Solving BVP**

In maple, we can solve the bvp "numerically, accurately and efficiently" with out any problem,

```
restart:with(plots):
ode:=diff(y(t),t,t)=y(t)^2-t:
bcs:=y(0)=0,y(N)=sqrt(N):
N:=50:
A1:=dsolve({ode,bcs},numeric):
odeplot(A1, [[t,y(t), color=red],[t,sqrt(t), color=green,linestyle=3]],0..N,axes=boxed)
```

[image]

Here is the value of `alpha`

```
 A1(0)
```

[image]

I am observing a  very strange behavior on *Mathematica*,

```
eq = y''[x] == y[x]^2 - x;
ibcs = {y[0] == 0, y[N1] == Sqrt[N1]};
sol = First@NDSolve[Join[{eq}, ibcs], y[x], {x, 0, N1}]
Plot[{y[x]} /. sol, {x, 0, N1}]
```

For `N1=4`, I get this

[image]

and for `N1=5`

[image]

**Is it possible, that there are multiple solutions? or there is something else going on?**

I am thankful to @halirutan for teaching me how to input the bc `y[x]=Sqrt[x]`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There are indeed two such solutions: one with a positive initial slope, and one with a negative one.