# n fold convolution of a function via a recursion function

Tags: functions, function-construction, recursion, convolution

I wanted to write a recursion function to calculate the n-th convolution of a function `f[x_]`. I wrote the function

```
g[f[x_], y_, z_] := Convolve[f[x], y, x, z]
```

where

```
f[x_] := \[Lambda]*
  Exp[-\[Lambda]*x/L]/((1 - Exp[-\[Lambda]])*L) UnitStep[x]
```

But now I want to put an `n` into the `g` function

```
g[f[x_], y_, z_,n_]
```

wich does the same n times! With `DO[...]` I have the problem the there is no output. How can I do it?
thanks in advanced

Comment: Are you looking for `Nest`?

Comment: I do not know `Nest`, do you think is it the solution? I checked it but the parameter z should be changed in every step, how can we manage it?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98576)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could also use:

```
cm[f_, s_, t_, n_] := 
 InverseLaplaceTransform[LaplaceTransform[f, s, t]^(n + 1), t, s]
```

(s>0):

e.g.

```
TableForm[Table[{j, cm[Exp[-a s] UnitStep[s], s, t, j]}, {j, 1, 10}], 
 TableHeadings -> {None, {"n", "n-fold Convolution"}}]
```

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised `InverseLaplaceTransform[]` even works… :)

Comment: @J.M. Actually so was I...I am sure it is brittle but  for some straight forward situations may be enough :)

Comment: @ubpdqn ok your solution is more elegant :) just one question: dose it work with every function, I mean e.g. with truncated exponential too?

Comment: @maniA I am not sure how robust it is. It may not work for your purposes. It appears to work with a number of functions. Apologies for delay: time zones :)

Comment: @ubpdqn  no matter thanks any way  :)  ok I tick  your response as the answer, however be warned  guys  that it may not work for the general case ;) then use just my proposal

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all who helped or tried to help me here, finally I found a solution. My special function was the exponential distribution  but one can apply it for any arbitrary function.

```
f[x_] = \[Lambda]*Exp[-\[Lambda]*x] UnitStep[x];
g[x_] = \[Lambda]*Exp[-\[Lambda]*x] UnitStep[x];
convi[n_] := {Do[
    g[x[i]] = Convolve[f[x[i - 1]], g[x[i - 1]], x[i - 1], x[i]], {i, 
     1, n}], g[x[n]]}[[2]]
```

and if you excuse for instance

```
convi[4]
```

you get the 4-fold convolution.