# Why doesn't the following code for recursive convolution work?

Tags: recursion, convolution

I'm trying to play with central limit theorem using *Mathematica*, so I wrote the following code,

```
f[x_] := UnitBox[x];  
For[i = 1, i < 4, i++,  
   f[x_] := Convolve[UnitBox[z], f[z], z, x]; 
    ]
Plot[f[x],{x,-3,3}]
```

hoping to produce a 3-fold convolution of the original function, but only to produce the following error notifications:

```
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of UnitBox[z].
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of UnitBox[z].
$RecursionLimit::reclim2: Recursion depth of 1024 exceeded during evaluation of UnitBox[z].
General::stop: Further output of $RecursionLimit::reclim2 will be suppressed during this calculation.
```

but I don't know how to comprehend this. What exactly is wrong with the code?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98576)?

Comment: @J.M., I saw that, but I'm too green to mathematica to understand the details of that post.

Comment: I think that because you use 'SetDelayed' rather than 'Set', only the last assignment to 'f (x)' has any effect.  Consequently, when you evaluate it, it calls itself recursively, without limit.

Comment: At the very least, did you see that you can use B-splines for this?

Comment: @J.M., I saw your answer, but I don't understand how B-spline works even after reading the Wiki introduction to B-splines.

Comment: Then, have you seen [this](http://www.idav.ucdavis.edu/education/CAGDNotes/Uniform-B-Splines-as-a-Convolution/Uniform-B-Splines-as-a-Convolution.html)?

Comment: @J.M., I see, then it's of limited utility for my interest, because I'm playing with central limit theorem, which needs to be true for many other initial functions.

Comment: Ah, then yes, the B-splines are specific to the convolutions of the box function. Nevertheless, the general solution in my other answer should be usable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is a more recursive solution

```
g[0] = UnitBox;
g[n_] := g[n] = Function[{x}, 
   Evaluate[Module[{z}, Convolve[UnitBox[z], g[n - 1][z], z, x]]]]

Plot[g[3][x], {x, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: This works very well, thanks and +1. But exactly what's wrong with my original code?

Comment: After some testing it seems what made the difference is "Evaluate", i.e. my code would also work if I enclose the "Convolve" with an "Evaluate". But I don't really understand the operating principle here.

Comment: When learning Mathematica, I found making it evaluate my functions in the order I intended was one of the biggest challenges. I admit that I gave you something that worked rather than trying very hard to understand what you had done.

Answer (score 3):

```
g[z_] := Nest[Convolve[#, UnitBox[x], x, z] &, UnitBox[x], 3];
Plot[g[z], {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

And try this, which is more instructive:

```
g[z_] := Nest[Convolve[#, UnitTriangle[x], x, z] &, UnitTriangle[x], 3];
Plot[g[z], {z, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Better to define `g` with [`Set`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html) than with [`SetDelayed`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SetDelayed.html) for this function; particularly so for the `UnitTriangle` version.

Comment: Better to include option, Exclusions -> None for the plot. It joins the skip zones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But does the first code block really produce a 3-fold convolution of UnitBox? I would expect the result of 3-fold convolution to be a (piece-wise) quadratic function.