# Nested integration

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I wish to perform the following nested integral:
\begin{align}
I_n=\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_n~f(x_n,x_{n+1})\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_{n-1}~f(x_{n-1},x_n)...\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_1~f(x_1,x_2)\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_0~f(x_0,x_1)
\end{align}
where $f$ is a known function. While this is easily done using `Do` loop (or something similar), I wished to make it more elegant using `Nest` and the function `f[x,y]`. But after several failed attempts I am beginning to wonder if this can be done at all. Any help in this regard is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't really need `Nest[]` for this. Taking into account *Mathematica*'s convention that the outermost integral corresponds to the first iterator in `Integrate[]`, we have

```
With[{n = 5}, 
     Integrate[Product[f[Subscript[x, k], Subscript[x, k + 1]], {k, 0, n}], 
               Sequence @@ Table[{Subscript[x, k], -∞, ∞}, {k, n, 0, -1}]]]
```

$$\scriptsize {\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }f\left(x_0,x_1\right) f\left(x_1,x_2\right) f\left(x_2,x_3\right) f\left(x_3,x_4\right) f\left(x_4,x_5\right) f\left(x_5,x_6\right)dx_0dx_1dx_2dx_3dx_4dx_5}$$

Comment: Oh, if this is the case, then I misinterpreted the formula and my answer is wrong.

Comment: Well, in "physicist's format", they usually put the integral and differential first before the function, so I interpreted it in that way, and (say) $x_1$ in both $f(x_0,x_1)$ and $f(x_1,x_2)$ should be scoped by the differential $\mathrm dx_1$. At least, that was my interpretation, and we should wait for the OP to clarify.

Comment: Yes, I know about the physical convention. Let's see.

Comment: @J.M. The rightmost integral is $g_1(x_1)\equiv\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_0 ~f(x_0,x_1)$. This gets fed into the next integral to obtain $g_2(x_2)\equiv\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_1 ~f(x_1,x_2)g_1(x_1)$, and so on. Does the structure of integral in your answer actually achieve this effect? Even then I would like to have a format in which I can compute $I_{k+1}$ given $I_k$ using $I_{k+1}\equiv\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx_n~f(x_{k+1},x_{k+2})I_k$, while outputting each $I_k$.

Comment: You don't have to take my word for it, @Deep; test the method yourself (just change the value of `n`) and you'll see that it evaluates exactly as you wanted it. I'll think about your recursive version, tho, but if you're impatient, you might get a few ideas from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/53).