# Dummy variable in nested integral operator

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, iteration

I am trying to make a nested integral operator where the output function of one step must be applied to the dummy variable to be integrated in the next step. Here my code:

```
w[x_] := Cos[x];
f[t_, n_] := Nest[Integrate[w[t - s] #, {s, 0, t}] &, 1, n];
```

Observe that, in one step, the output function is applied in $t$ and not $s$. Therefore, in the next integration, $t$ is just a constant, but it must be integrated as well. How can I fix this?

Comment: In the simplest form, you want something like `f[0, t_] := 1; f[n_Integer?Positive, t_] := Integrate[Cos[t - s] f[n - 1, s], {s, 0, t}]`. The more efficient method involves using the method in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/60).

Comment: Does changing `#` to `((#) /. t -> s)` in `f` get you what you need?

Comment: @J.M., it worked! Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @Edmund, thank you for your tip too!