# Recursive Function with conditionals

Tags: recursion, homework

Function:
[image]

I am to solve for $T_{12}(4.8), T_{24}(1.2)$, using **If** and **Which** functions.

I started with this function and keep getting a recursion limit error:

```
t[n_] := (7/2 x) t[n - 1] - (7/2) t[n + 1]
```

Comment: `RSolve` may help.

Comment: because you haven't set a boundary condition.

Comment: It seems a duplicate question is posted. Please see [my solution here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/214431/12924).

Answer (score 1):

```
T[x_, n_] := Block[{temp = n}, Which[
temp == 0, Return[1], temp == 1, Return[x], temp > 1, 
1/x T[x, temp - 2] - 2/7 T[x, temp - 1]]]
```

T[1, 4] gives

> 167/343

Or as what you want.

```
T[n_] := Block[{temp = n}, 
Which[temp == 0, Return[1], temp == 1, Return[x], temp > 1,
1/x T[temp - 2] - 2/7 T[temp - 1]]]
T[4] /. x -> 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
T[0] = 1;
T[1] = x;
T[n_] := (1/x) T[n - 2] - (2/7) T[n - 1];
```

Comment: I would recommend `T[n_] := T[n] = (1/x)...`. Without memoization, this recursion is going to be awfully inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Clear[T, n, x]
Tn = T[n] /. RSolve[{T[n + 1] == 1/x T[n - 1] - 2/7 T[n], T[0] == 1, T[1] == x}, T, n][[1]]

Tn /. {n -> 12, x -> 4.8}

(* -0.0153785 *)
```