# Numerically solving a multivariable integro-differential equation

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, integral-equations

I have an integro-differential equation of the form,

$$\small\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial t}=\int_{-5}^5 |x-y|\,f\left(-\frac{x}{3}+\frac{4y}{3},t\right)\,f\left(\frac{2x}{3}+\frac{y}{3},t\right)\,\mathrm dy-\int_{-5}^5 |x-y|\,f(x,t)\,f(y,t)\,\mathrm dy$$

I have the function $f(x,0)$ representing the function at $t=0$. I want to numerically integrate the above equation to find the function $f(x,t)$ at any time $t$. I tried using `NDSolveValue` but Mathematica says the system is underdetermined. I'll be glad if someone can let me know if this can be solved using Mathematica.

This is my code, FYI

```
x1[x_, y_] = -x/3 + 4*(y/3);

y1[x_, y_] = 2*(x/3) + y/3; 

eqn = D[f[x, t], t] == Integrate[Abs[x - y]*f[x1[x_, y_], t]*f[y1[x_, y_], t], {y, -5, 5}] - Integrate[Abs[x - y]*f[x, t]*f[y, t], {y, -5, 5}];

init = f[x, 0] == 1/10; 

sol2 = NDSolveValue[{eqn, init}, f[x, t], {{x,-5,5}, {t, 0, 100}}];
```

Thanks a lot,

Comment: From **Documentation** `NDSolve` or `NDSolveValue` this type equation can't solve.

Comment: You equation does not contain any spatial derivatives and no spatial singularities, and so you may be able to solve it using a simple interpolation scheme. Even order-zero interpolation may be sufficient here if the grid is chosen fine enough.

Comment: The solution is the trivial $f(x,t)=\frac{1}{10}$, isn't it?

Comment: No..f(x,t) behaves like a gaussian at large times...The above equation is a form of the famous Boltzmann transport equation, which converges to maxwell distribution at large times.

Comment: You need to add @xzczd in your comment or I won't get the reminder. Why do you think $f(x,t)=\frac{1}{10}$ isn't a solution?

Comment: @xzczd, oops, You're right.....Let me check where the issue is...

Answer (score 7):

We need a functional to evaluate the right-hand-side from a given function $f$:

```
xmin = -5;
xmax = 5;
rhs[f_, x_ /; xmin <= x <= xmax] :=
  NIntegrate[Abs[x - y]*f[(4 y - x)/3]*f[(2 x + y)/3], {y, xmin, xmax}] -
  f[x]*NIntegrate[Abs[x - y]*f[y], {y, xmin, xmax}]
```

Given a function $f_t(x)$ and a time step $\Delta t$, propagate the function forward in time (using the [Euler method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_method)) and return the new function $f_{t+\Delta t}(x)$:

```
propagate[f_, Δt_?Positive] := 
  Evaluate@Piecewise[{{FunctionInterpolation[f[x] + Δt*rhs[f, x], {x, xmin, xmax}][#],
                       xmin <= # <= xmax}}] &
```

The integro-differential equation can now be solved: starting from a function `F[0]` at $t=0$ and progressing by time-steps $\Delta t$ using the simple Euler method above, using [partial memoization](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/201001/26598) to save an [InterpolatingFunction](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InterpolatingFunction.html) object at every time step:

```
Δt = 1/100;
Clear[F];
F[0] = Piecewise[{{1/(xmax - xmin), xmin <= # <= xmax}}] &;
F[t_?Positive] := F[t] = propagate[F[t - Δt], Δt]
F[x_?NumericQ, t_?NonNegative] := F[Round[t, Δt]][x]
```

The function `F[x,t]` represents the solution, but keep in mind that the $t$-coordinate has a resolution of $\Delta t$ and the $x$-coordinate has a finite resolution because it is represented as an interpolation. Using a smaller $\Delta t$ makes the solution more accurate but takes more time.

```
ContourPlot[F[x, t], {t, 0, 2}, {x, xmin, xmax},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, FrameLabel -> {t, x}]
```

[image]

Possible improvements:

- Use a better way to propagate, for example a [Runge–Kutta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods) or even a Mathematica built-in functionality.
- Adapt the options of [`NIntegrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NIntegrate.html) and [`FunctionInterpolation`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionInterpolation.html) to increase accuracy and/or speed.

Comment: There's a typo in the definition of `rhs`. `f[x]*NIntegrate[Abs[x - y]*f[y], {y, xmin, xmax}]` should be `NIntegrate[Abs[x - y]*f[x]*f[y], {y, xmin, xmax}]` according to the question.

Comment: @xzczd constant factors can be pulled out of the integral.

Comment: Oops…you're right. But, though I can't tell what the exact reason is, the numeric error in the solution seems to be a bit large? $f(x,t)=\frac{1}{10}$ is the solution, right?

Comment: @xzczd the solution is constant in time only if you disregard the boundaries. The OP is not very clear on this topic. I've made all functions `Piecewise[{{..., xmin <= x <= xmax}}]` instead of allowing nonzero values outside of the domain $[x_{\text{min}},x_{\text{max}}]$. In this case, the constant function no longer solves the equation, because it is only constant on this interval and zero outside. Carification from the OP is needed if this is a problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Roman, Your explanation was convincing that as long as the cross-terms lie inside the bound, constant 1/10 is always the solution. Else, it'll slowly converge to the gaussian. However, I'm yet to figure out what it means physically.....