# How to memoize with patterns?

Tags: performance-tuning, argument-patterns, memoization, downvalues

Here is an artificial example to explain what I am up to. Define

```
ClearAll[f]
f[x_, y_] := f[x, y] = If[x == 0, g[y], g[f[x - 1, y]]]
```

Then `AbsoluteTiming[f[10, y]]` gives

`{0.0000863, g[g[g[g[g[g[g[g[g[g[g[y]]]]]]]]]]]}`,

whereafter `AbsoluteTiming[f[5, y]]` gives

`{6.2*10^-6, g[g[g[g[g[g[y]]]]]]}`.

However after that `AbsoluteTiming[f[5, z]]` gives

`{0.0000487, g[g[g[g[g[g[z]]]]]]}`,

i. e. with `z` it takes more time than with `y`. This is because the remembered downvalues of `f` before evaluating at `z` only involve the variable `y` - for example, `HoldPattern[f[2, y]] :> g[g[g[y]]]` is among them.

If I could memoize something like `HoldPattern[f[2, y_]] :> g[g[g[y]]]` instead (that is, with pattern `y_` instead of the hardwired variable `y`), would not the result be more efficient? If no, why? If yes, how to do it?

Comment: If the solutions in the linked thread do not apply to your problem, please edit your question to explain what doesn't work in your actual problem.

Comment: @J.M. Oh thanks - I honestly searched but could not find it. But I am not sure whether to delete my question or not: certainly the answers to that question easily answer mine. On the other hand, it might be that for somebody with a similar question this one is easier to find. What would you do?

Comment: @J.M. Also, these answers, although all beautiful, are quite different. Do you remember which one was the most useful for you?

Comment: I think keeping this dupe is fine; as you say, this particular instance uses different keywords that would still be picked up by search. As for what I settled with, I used Leonid's solution a lot.